# (Python) Counting lines in a huge (>10GB) file as fast as possible

Tags: python, enumerate, line-count

I have a really simple script right now that counts lines in a text file using `enumerate()`:

```
i = 0
f = open("C:/Users/guest/Desktop/file.log", "r")
for i, line in enumerate(f):
      pass
print i + 1
f.close()
```

This takes around 3 and a half minutes to go through a 15GB log file with ~30 million lines. It would be great if I could get this under two minutes or less, because these are daily logs and we want to do a monthly analysis, so the code will have to process 30 logs of ~15GB - more than one and a half hour possibly, and we'd like to minimise the time & memory load on the server.

I would also settle for a good approximation/estimation method, but it needs to be about 4 sig fig accurate...

Thank you!

Comment: In general it would probably be faster to treat the file as binary data, read through it in reasonably-sized chunks (say, 4KB at a time), and count the `\n` characters in each chunk as you go.

Comment: This is not better performing than your naive solution, but fyi the pythonic way to write what you have here would be simply `with open(fname) as f: print sum(1 for line in f)`

Comment: aroth: Thanks for the tip, I should look into that.
wim: great, thanks, that's much shorter...

Comment: Take a look at [rawbigcount](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27517681/3420199) at Michael Bacon's answer. It may be helpful you!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629179/python-counting-lines-in-a-huge-10gb-file-as-fast-as-possible/9629202#9629202) is correct, but might fail if you have a 32 bit process.

But maybe it could be useful to read the file block-wise and then count the `\n` characters in each block.

```
def blocks(files, size=65536):
    while True:
        b = files.read(size)
        if not b: break
        yield b

with open("file", "r") as f:
    print sum(bl.count("\n") for bl in blocks(f))
```

will do your job.

Note that I don't open the file as binary, so the `\r\n` will be converted to `\n`, making the counting more reliable.

For Python 3, and to make it more robust, for reading files with all kinds of characters:

```
def blocks(files, size=65536):
    while True:
        b = files.read(size)
        if not b: break
        yield b

with open("file", "r",encoding="utf-8",errors='ignore') as f:
    print (sum(bl.count("\n") for bl in blocks(f)))
```

Comment: Just as one data point, a read of a large file of about 51 MB went from about a minute using the naive approach to under one second using this approach.

Comment: @MKatz What now, "a large file" or "a file of about 51 MB"? ;-)

Comment: this solution might miss out the last line but that might not matter for a huge file.

Comment: @ngọcminh.oss Only if the last line is incomplete. A text file is defined to end with a line break, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/729795/296974.

Comment: not that people care about definition. when you work with real data, everything is messy. but it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Re missing lines (i.e. lines that don't end in a "line break"): Relatively unimportant, I suppose, if the file is large.  But I have files that vary from huge to one-liners.  Unfortunately, some of the one-liners lack a trailing newline, and the program that uses this function assumes a return value of 0 means an empty file...which may not be true.  So I had to do some other checking.

Answer (score 24):

I know its a bit unfair but you could do this

```
int(subprocess.check_output("wc -l C:\\alarm.bat").split()[0])
```

If you're on Windows, check out [Coreutils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/5.3.0/coreutils-5.3.0.exe/download).

Comment: My solution takes only 1m37 real time.

Comment: this is far faster

Comment: Seems like you need to do `int(subprocess.check_output("/usr/bin/wc -l cred", shell=True).split()[0])` for python3

Comment: If you have large files or a lot of files, please consider using this approach if you are looking for pure performance without resorting to another language.

Answer (score 17):

A fast, 1-line solution is:

```
sum(1 for i in open(file_path, 'rb'))
```

It should work on files of arbitrary size.

Comment: I confirm that this is the fastest one (except the `wc -l` hack). Using the text mode gives a little dropdown in performance, but it is insignificant in comparison with other solutions.

Comment: There is an unneeded extra generator parenthesis, btw.

Comment: Without the unneeded extra generator parenthesis， it appears to be sligntly faster (per timeit) and consumes about 3MB less memory (per memit for a file of 100,000 lines)..

Comment: doesn't seem to work if the file is a text file with newlines. My problem are large txt files that need character counting.

Comment: The file is not closed.

Answer (score 6):

[mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) the file, and count up the newlines.

```
import mmap

def mapcount(filename):
    with open(filename, "r+") as f:
        buf = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
        lines = 0
        readline = buf.readline
        while readline():
            lines += 1
        return lines
```

Comment: Please consider adding a short example to demonstrate this, thanks!

Comment: short example might be a good idea, I agree

Comment: Why is this faster when we'd expect the speed to be I/O bound? Does this load/read the file faster from disk? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

I'd extend gl's answer and run his/her code using multiprocessing Python module for faster count:

```
def blocks(f, cut, size=64*1024): # 65536
    start, chunk =cut
    iter=0
    read_size=int(size)
    _break =False
    while not _break:
        if _break: break
        if f.tell()+size>start+chunk:
            read_size=int(start+chunk- f.tell() )
            _break=True
        b = f.read(read_size)
        iter +=1
        if not b: break
        yield b


def get_chunk_line_count(data):
    fn,  chunk_id, cut = data
    start, chunk =cut
    cnt =0
    last_bl=None

    with open(fn, "r") as f:
        if 0:
            f.seek(start)
            bl = f.read(chunk)
            cnt= bl.count('\n')
        else:
            f.seek(start)
            for i, bl  in enumerate(blocks(f,cut)):
                cnt +=  bl.count('\n')
                last_bl=bl

        if not last_bl.endswith('\n'):
            cnt -=1

        return cnt
....
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,
                            initializer=start_process,
                            )
pool_outputs = pool.map(get_chunk_line_count, inputs)
pool.close() # no more tasks
pool.join()
```

This will improve counting performance 20 folds.
I wrapped it to a [script](https://github.com/alexbuz/Fast-line-counter-using-Python-multiprocessing/blob/master/count_lines.py) and put it to Github.

Comment: @olekb Thank you for sharing the multiprocessing approach. Quick question as a newbie, how do we run this code to count a line in a big file (say, 'myfile.txt')? Do I tried `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4); pool_outputs = pool.map(get_chunk_line_count, 'myfile.txt')`, but that causes error. Thank you in advanced for your answer!