# Calculating total lines of code in a directory

Tags: recursion, lua, filesystems

I have a directory with several sub-directories and they all have .lua files.
I want to calculate the lines of code in all files total.

I have experience in lua, but I've never done file system stuff, so I'm new to this. I understand I would have to recursively iterate the main folder, but I'm not familiar with how the io library works, so if anyone could explain to me how to do this I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Is using Lua a requirement? You can use a quick Python script to do that.

Like so:

```
import os

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if i.endswith(".lua"): 
        with open(i) as f:
            num_lines = sum(1 for _ in f)
            print i + str(num_lines)
            # Do whatever else you want to do with the number of lines
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

That will print the number of lines of each file in the current working directory.

Partial code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001475/1021259) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378012/1021259).

Comment: No, not a requirement, it's just the only programming language I have installed.

Comment: Ah. I believe [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/) tutorial has a section on setting up the Python environment. Note that the code I provided is for Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: On Linux you could do `find . -name "*.lua" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`. (If you use another OS, I'm sure there are tutorials out there for setting up Linux.)

Comment: Your code seems to result in:  NameError: name "os" is not defined

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to say you have to import stuff. Just put `import os` at the start of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I used LuaFileSystem and it seems to work fine.
Thanks to Rob Rose for the python example though, even though I did not get it to work properly.

```
require("lfs")
local numlines = 0

function attrdir (path)
    for file in lfs.dir(path) do
        if file ~= "." and file ~= ".." then
            local f = path..'/'..file
            local attr = lfs.attributes (f)
            assert(type(attr) == "table")
            if attr.mode == "directory" then
                attrdir(f)
            else
                --print(f)
                --f = io.open(f, "r")
                for line in io.lines(f) do
                numlines = numlines + 1
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function main()
    attrdir(".")
    print("total lines in working directory: "..numlines)
end

local s,e = pcall(main)
if not s then
    print(e)
end
io.read()
```