# How do i print/return the number of lines in a file

Tags: python, file, count, readline, lines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

I'd like to print how many lines there is in a file.

What I have so far is this, but it prints the number of every line and I'm not sure how to get Python to only print the last one.

```
filename = input('Filename: ')

f= open(filename,'r') 

counter = 1 

line = f.readline() 
while(line): 
    clean_line = line.strip() 
    print(counter) 
    line = f.readline()
    counter += 1
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to loop on each line, you could just use:

```
counter = len(f.readlines())
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know i could use the len function here!

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for...

```
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    print sum(1 for line in fin)
```

This saves reading the file into memory to take its length.

Comment: Best solution here.  I was being overwhelmingly lazy.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
number_of_lines = len(lines)
f.close()
```