# Fastest way to find total lines in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

a want to find total lines in a text file using python, 
an easy solution is to iterate over lines using `open('file.txt') and count them.

can anybody introduce me a better solution?

Comment: use `wc -l` and not `python` :-)

Comment: this is part of my application, that must be cross platform.

Comment: @mgilson `wc -l` might not work in windows.

Comment: Good duplicate question - my first choice would be my deleted answer using sum, and my second would have been mmap - oh well - got it all covered on that one :)

Comment: Are you doing this on huge text files and is efficiency a primary concern?

Comment: @JonClements I had the same question earlier today, so it took me no time to search again. :)

Comment: @paddy: yes, my problem is textfiles greater that 100GB.

Comment: There's no better way, _unless_ something is known about the file structure (like "all lines are no less than 80 chars long").