# Count line no. using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

In my work i need to open a file and count no. of lines in that, i tried with this

`Last_Line = len(open(File_Name).readlines())`

It was working fine. Now i have a problem, actual no. of lines in the file is 453, but if i print `Last_Line` it is showing only 339. If i try

```
print linecache.getline(File_Name, 350)
```

it is displaying the contents of line no. 350.

I tried opening the file in all modes.
Whether its problem with file or with my logic?
Please help.

thank you

Comment: What does "all modes" mean? Did you try universal line ending mode?

Comment: Not a duplicate. That one asks "how do I do it?", this one asks "what's wrong with how I'm doing it?".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I tried with these modes,'r','rb', 'r+'

Comment: What kind of file is it? Can you try a different file?

Comment: How is it you determined the number of lines to be 453?

Comment: @ATOzTOA Its a c header file, Every other file works fine.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber can see line no. in IDE

Comment: @user1752489 Which IDE? What is the IDE setting for the type of line ending?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber Using Code blocks on windows. Eol is in standard windows form CRLF

Comment: @Antony Hatchkins linecache is to read any line in a file
http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html

Comment: **Do not remove the system-generated banner.  Doing so may lead to further moderator action.  CONSIDER THOSE BANNERS OFF LIMITS WHEN IT COMES TO EDITING.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mixed line endings. Your IDE is treating them all as valid, while Python is not. Open the file with the universal newlines flag `"U"` to have Python take them all as valid line endings.

```
>>> f = open("file.txt", "w")
>>> f.write("a\rb\nc\r\nd\n\re\n")
>>> f.close()
>>> open("file.txt").readlines()
['a\rb\n', 'c\r\n', 'd\n', '\re\n']
>>> open("file.txt", 'rU').readlines()
['a\n', 'b\n', 'c\n', '\n', 'd\n', '\n', 'e\n']
```

The documentation for `linecache` does not appear to specify how it handles line endings. Empirically, it uses universal newlines:

```
>>> for n in range(1, 8):
...   linecache.getline('file.txt', n)
...
'a\n'
'b\n'
'c\n'
'\n'
'd\n'
'\n'
'e\n'
```