# python csv distorts tell

Tags: python, csv, tell

I am trying to find a percent of where I am when reading through a csv file.  I know how I could do this using tell() with a file object, but when I read that file object using csv.reader, then do a for loop on the rows in my reader object, the tell() function always returns as if it is at the end of the file, no matter where I am in the loop.  How can I find where I am?

Current code:

```
with open(FILE_PERSON, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    justtesting = csvfile.tell()
    size = os.fstat(csvfile.fileno()).st_size
    for row in spamreader:
        pos = csvfile.tell()
        print pos, "of", size, "|", justtesting
```

I threw "justtesting" in there just to prove that tell() does return 0 until I start my for loop.

This will return the same thing for every row in my csv file:
579 of 579 | 0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `csv` library utilizes a buffer when reading your file, so the file pointer jumps in larger blocks. It does *not* read your file line-by-line.

It reads the data in larger chunks to make parsing easier, and because newlines could be embedded in quotes, reading CSV data line-by-line would not work.

If you *have* to give a progress report, then you need to pre-count the number of lines. The following will only work if your input CSV file does not embed newlines in column values:

```
with open(FILE_PERSON, 'rb') as csvfile:
    linecount = sum(1 for _ in csvfile)
    csvfile.seek(0)
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line, row in enumerate(spamreader):
        print '{} of {}'.format(line, linecount)
```

There are other methods to count the number of lines (see [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)) but since you'll be reading the file *anyway* to process it as a CSV, you may as well make use of the open file you have for that. I'm not certain that opening the file as a memory map, then read it as a normal file again is going to perform any better.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, so is there any efficient way of determining how far along I am?  I know I can do rows=list(spamreader), then for rownum, row in enumerate(rows): but I have read that is very inefficient. Is there any other trick?

Comment: @BlairConnolly: Added one for you. It *will* read through the whole file to count the number of lines first.

Comment: You don't need to cast to `list` before calling `enumerate` -- you can just do `for row in enumerate(spamreader)` and that is equally efficient.

Comment: @katrielalex: I think there is a `len(rows)` missing there. That would make it easier to know how many rows there are still to be processed. :-)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.  As you've probably figured out, I'm new to Python, and your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`csvreader` docs say:

> ... csvfile can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its next() method is called ...

Therefore a small change to the OP's original code:

```
import csv
import os
filename = "tar.data"
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    justtesting = csvfile.tell()
    size = os.fstat(csvfile.fileno()).st_size
    for row in spamreader:
        pos = csvfile.tell()
        print pos, "of", size, "|", justtesting
###############################################
def generator(csvfile):
    # readline seems to be the key
    while True:
        line = csvfile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        yield line
###############################################
print
with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(generator(csvfile))
    justtesting = csvfile.tell()
    size = os.fstat(csvfile.fileno()).st_size
    for row in spamreader:
        pos = csvfile.tell()
        print pos, "of", size, "-", justtesting
```

Running this against my test data gives the following, showing that the two different approaches produce different results.

```
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0
224 of 224 | 0

16 of 224 - 0
32 of 224 - 0
48 of 224 - 0
64 of 224 - 0
80 of 224 - 0
96 of 224 - 0
112 of 224 - 0
128 of 224 - 0
144 of 224 - 0
160 of 224 - 0
176 of 224 - 0
192 of 224 - 0
208 of 224 - 0
224 of 224 - 0
```

I set zero buffering on the `open` but it made no difference, the thing is `readline` in the generator.