# How to see how many members are there in a list?

Tags: python-2.7

I actually have two questions.

```
lines = file.readlines()
```

1.) Is variable lines a list?

2.) How to see how many elements are there in a list?

Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('p7.erl', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print type(lines)
    print len(lines)
```

outputs:

```
<type 'list'>
27
```

so yes, lines is a list and you can find out how many elements are in the by `len` function.

If you are only interested in number of lines in a file see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: Thank you very much!
I would vote up but I'm level 13, and I must be 15.

May I ask why do you use
    with open('p7.erl', 'r') as f:
instead of
    f = open('p7.erl', 'r')
?
I think it's all about personal preferences, isn't it?

Comment: You don't have to worry about closing the file (eg: an exception occurs before you close it) after you are done with it if you use `with`. It will be taken care of when you go outside with block. You can read upon with [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to understand it better.