# TypeError: "NoneType" object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, file, object

I have this error when running this code with Python:

> TypeError: "NoneType" object is unsubscriptable".

**Code:**

```
number = 0

with open('playlist.txt') as read_number_lines:
    for line in read_number_lines:
        if line.strip():
            number += 1

number = number - 1
print 'number: ', number

for i in range(number):
    author_ = raw_input('author: ')
    line = input('line: ')
    file = open('playlist.txt','a').writelines(' - ' + author_)[line]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: `writelines(' - ' + author_)[line]` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Write the author at the specific line, next to the song's title.

Comment: Post your expected output, you just can't write at any line number you want using `file.writelines`.

Comment: For the line count: [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems in

```
file = open('playlist.txt','a').writelines(' - ' + author_)[line]
```

The immediate source of your error is that `.writelines()` doesn't return anything (so it returns `None`) which you're trying to index using `[line]`. That produces your error.

Also, you shouldn't be calling that method on the `open()` call directly.

The entire second `for` loop is mysterious to me. You're opening that file again during each iteration of the loop (which you don't want to do; it probably wouldn't even work).

Perhaps you wanted to do something like

```
with open('playlist.txt','a') as file:
    for i in range(number):
        author_ = raw_input('author: ')
        line = raw_input('line: ')
        file.write(author + " - " + line)
```

but it's still hard to see the point of this...

Comment: I think `line` is the line number at which OP is trying to write the content.

Comment: The variable 'line' is an integer that I use for link the write's line. Author will be the string written in line selected by me. :)

Comment: You can't index a file like this. You should read the file into a list (using `.readlines()`) and work on that list, then write the whole list back to a new file using `.writelines()`. But that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Tim, an example for this?

Comment: You should open a new question for this.