# Retrieving number of lines with python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the number of lines of a file using python on ubuntu.

I tried the following:

```
os.system("wc -l fileName")
```

But it returns something like

```
numberOfLines fileName
0
```

When I tried to retrieve the result:
    l = os.system("wc -l fileName")

I got `l = 0`

I also tried to split the result in order to keep the first element only, but this raises `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'`

How can I get the number of lines I am looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

os.system will return the exit value of the `wc -l` command, which is zero if no error occurs.

You want the actual output of the program:

```
#TODO: handle CalledProcessError, malformatted output where appropriate

wc_output = subprocess.check_output(["wc", "-l", fileName])
num_lines = int(wc_output.split()[0])
```

Comment: It's worth knowing that `wc` prints the filename if it's an argument, but not if counting lines from stdin.

Comment: @w.m Similarly, I tried subprocess.check_output(["ls","files*"]) but got an error telling the file files* doesn't exist. How can I specify that I want all the files whose name begins with files?

Comment: @w.m er, not that my happiness has anything to do with it, but wouldn't it be better just to redirect the file to stdin for wc, rather than using split?

Comment: @bigTree lookup glob/globbing and maybe the shell=True flag (and its security warnings)

Comment: @kojiro you'd have to open the file in Python or use shell=True though?

Comment: @w.m Depends how the script is run. You could always do the redirect before executing the script. But opening the file in Python would be a reasonable way.

Comment: @kojiro Hm, ok. And with the shell thing I wasn't sure whether you meant check_output("wc -l < filename", shell=True), because that would work too, I guess.