# Python error due to version?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to run a basic random sentence generator to test my web server for python... all it does is open 3 files and randomly pick a line from each.

It *does* run fine on my laptop but on the web server it fails and generates a syntax error for one part of the code (a part I got from another stack overflow question here -  [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python) ).

The error is:

```
  File "sentence.py", line 17
    with open(fname) as f:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the part with the error is:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

The server is using Python 2.4.3

Does anyone see an immediate problem here?

Comment: The `with` statement wasn't introduced until Python 2.5

Comment: Running such an old Python on a web server is probably not a good idea.  Python 2.4.3 was released in 2006.  The last bugfix for 2.4 was released 2008.  I encourage you to update your Python to a more recent version.  You will not only gain access to more features, but also get less bugs and more security fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is only available in Python 2.5 and newer:

> *New in version 2.5.*

Use a `try..finally` construct instead:

```
def file_len(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    try:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    finally:
        f.close()
    return i + 1
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked great! Can't upgrade server yet as they won't let me... but they are going to sort it soon. For now this is a useful workaround. Sorry for the duplicate question... I'll be more careful in future.