# Search directories for multi line string

Tags: python

Looking for a way to recursively search a repository for all files containing a multi line string and return the file names that contain it.  The paragraph is just a header approx 30 lines.

Below is the approach I am taking but is not working.

```
repo = os.getcwd()

header = """ /*
             /* .......paragraph
             /* ..............
             */
         """

for file in glob.glob(repo):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if header in contents:
        print file
```

I am getting this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/test/python/repos/projects/one'
```

Edited new version @zondo

```
def findAllFiles(directory):
    gen = os.walk(directory)
    next(gen)
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for path, _, files in gen for f in files]

def main():
    print "Searching directory for copyright header"
    for file in findAllFiles(repo):
        with open(file) as f:
            contents = f.read()
    if header in contents:
        print file
```

Comment: You've got error because trying to open directory, check whether it's `file` before (method `os.path.isfile`)

Comment: @andriy-ivaneyko But I don't want to individually open all files there are 100's of files. It is a git repository so there are multiple directories with many files

Comment: Quite similar yours question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `os` module, you can do this:

```
# Find not only all files in a folder, but all files in all sub-directories
def find_all_files(folder):
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for path, _, files in os.walk(folder) for f in files]

for file in find_all_files(repo):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        if header in contents:
            print file
```

Comment: Doesnt return anything. Am I doing something wrong? Posted my implementation above

Comment: @homeGrown I can't help you there.  Are you sure that the header is contained in at least one file?

Comment: yes it is in numerous files. Is my implementation posted in question correct yes?

Comment: @homeGrown You need to indent the `if header in contents:` and the line below it so that they are within the `with` block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102489/discussion-between-homegrown-and-zondo).

Answer (score 0):

Try using subprocess and pcregrep for matching multiple lines in different directories.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["pcregrep", "-rM","<regular_exp>","<path to directory>"])
```

Never tried this. Just came to my mind

Comment: To only search .c and .h files I used  `call(["pcregrep", "-rM", "%s" % header,"--include=*.{c,h}",  "%s" % repo])` But the results are coming out with pcregrep: check the --buffer-size option