# How to count unique names in a file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to count how many non-empty lines are there and my code is working but I failed to count if there is the same name in different lines, for example

```
john 01/2
jack 01/2

john 02/3
```

because I want to count lines with repeated names (and different dates)
as one

---

```
def number_people(path):

    x = 0
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
                x += 1
    return x
```

Comment: and there is no blank lines

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

Comment: What do you excpect to happen if there is `john 01/2` and `jack 01/2`?

Comment: its possible to have same person in the same text file but with different date so I'm trying to calculate them as one

Comment: i am expecting it to count it as 1 because the names are same

Comment: i already did the function but i am stuck with counting the same person as one @Fredrik Pih

Comment: compare sub strings ... if there is a match don't count. you need to notice what you will do in a situation : john 01/2  jack 01/1  john 01/3.  there is a match between 1 and 3. This is a a school question.

Comment: You need to start by actually *doing something* with the names rather than just counting lines. Hint: I'd use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to remove duplicates and then just get the length of the set at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the line always looks like 'Name Date':

```
def number_people(path):
    x = 0
    namesList = [] # Make a list of names
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            try:
                name, date = line.split(' ') # if there's a space in between
                if name not in names: # If the name is not in namesList...
                    x += 1
                    namesList.append(name) # put the name in namesList
            except ValueError:
                print(line)
                #pass
    return x
```

**EDIT**

Fixing ValueError. Note: it now skips lines that do not match the `split` condition. It now prints the lines that do not match, but you can also skip them (`pass`) and continue.

Comment: well, in that case your line doesn't look like 'Name Date'.

Comment: Try a `print(line)` on the line above the `line.split(' ')` to see what the line looks like.

Comment: and it is not printing the whole line when i try print line

Comment: Can you show the exact error message? And a sample of what it is printing?

Comment: name, date = line.split(' ') # if there's a space in between
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: printed James 11/21 12/11 instead of James 11/21 James 12/11 John 12/11

Comment: You should try something like `for line in f: print(line)` and outcomment the rest, because it almost has to be a problem in your file (probably not consistent)...

Comment: i'm trying to count the lines only not printing it and now it is printing all of it

Comment: I know. But you're code doesn't work, does it? So you'll have to figure out what's wrong first, and [that's what you do by printing](https://www.codementor.io/python/tutorial/how-to-debug-python-code-beginners-print-line). Those lines can be outcommented later, when the script works.

Answer (score 0):

The function `len` gives you the lenght of an iterable, here a `set`

Here `set` is applied to a generator expression, and retains only the generated items that are unique, so that `len(set(...))` gives you the number of different elements that are generated by `...`

The generator expression operates on the lines `l` of your file, discarding the empty lines, and for each line we `split` it, obtaining a two element list, retaining the first element only that is the name of a person.

To sum it up
`sequence of names -> set -> unique names -> len -> number of unique names`
and this translates to the following function definition

```
def number_people(path):
    return len(set(l.split()[0] for l in open(path) if l.strip()))
```