# Get length of Stata file in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, io, stata

I am using Pandas to read in a Stata file with the StataReader object, as in:

```
import pandas as pd
reader = pd.read_stata('file.dta', iterator = True)
```

Is there a way to get the number of rows in the file before I start using `reader.get_chunk` to iterate through chunks?

Comment: isn't this a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

Comment: I think that would be true if each line in a Stata file corresponded to an entry, but they don't.

Comment: I guess the cruddy way would be to have a counter object like `count=0` declared outside a loop and do `for chunk in pd.read_stata('file.dta', iterator=True) count += len(chunk)`

Comment: I guess you could just read in a single line and check `memory_usage()`. Then divide the file size by that?  Ought to get you very close as I don't think stata dataset have any compression built in.