# Print number of lines found

Tags: python

New to programming here and was wondering if anyone could help me out:

I'm trying to print or return the number of lines found in the below code using one line and I can't figure it out.

```
query = raw_input("Enter string to search for: ")
for line in open("list2.csv"):
    if query in line:
        print line,
```

Comment: You will have to read the whole file anyway but you can do  it in a single line using a list comprehension. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension like this:

```
with open("list2.csv") as f:
 print(sum(query in line for line in f))  #gives number of lines found
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just a suggestion: use a genexp in place if the list comp. `sum(query in line for line in f)`. There is no need for the intermediate list of `bool`

Answer (score 0):

There have been identical questions asked on here:

[How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Here is the method that thread provides:

```
def file_len(fname):
with open(fname) as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        pass
return i + 1
```

Search is your friend :).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for clarity that you avoid using just a single line! Here is something that should work:

```
query = raw_input("Enter string to search for: ")
lines = []
for line in open("list2.csv"):
    if query in line:
        lines.append(line)
        print line,
print "Number of lines:", len(lines)
```

If you really wanted a single line, you could do the following:

```
query = raw_input("Enter string to search for: ")
print "Number of lines:", len([line for line in open("list2.csv") if query in line])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be the best option, but it's the easiest.

Add a counter to your `if` statement to increase by one for every time the `if` statement executes.

Try this:

```
counter = 0
query = raw_input("Enter string to search for: ")
for line in open("list2.csv"):
    if query in line:
        print line
        counter += 1
return counter
```