# AttributeError File object has no attribute 'raw' Error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following [code written by Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27518377/4354477)  for finding linecount cheaply but when I run it it gives me an error as `AttributeError File object has no attribute 'raw'` Error and I am not sure why this is occurring. Below is the code for reference any help is highly appreciated

```
from itertools import (takewhile,repeat)

def _make_gen(reader):
    b = reader(1024 * 1024)
    while b:
        yield b
        b = reader(1024*1024)

def rawpycount(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    f_gen = _make_gen(f.raw.read)
    return sum( buf.count(b'\n') for buf in f_gen )
```

Comment: Re-read the answer, especially: "This only applies in Python 3."

Comment: Sorry missed that part but is there anyother way to run on Python 2.7?

Comment: I think it should just be `f.read`, python 3 works with unicode directly, python 2.7 works with bytes directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `_make_gen(f.raw.read)` to `_make_gen(f.read)`.

Python 3.x using unicode by default, hence the `raw` to convert to bytes. On the other hand, Python 2.x using bytes by default so no need for anything else.