# How to delete a line from a file by index?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

Pretty self explanatory. This is my text file:

```
C:\Windows\Users\Public\Documents\
C:\Program Files\Text Editor\
```

So, I have code which prompts the user to input the number of the line he wants to delete. But how do I delete the line which corresponds to the number?

**EDIT :**

To the person asking code:

```
# Viewing presets
if pathInput.lower() == 'view': 
    # Prints the lines in a numbered, vertical list.
    numLines = 1

    numbered = ''
    for i in lines:
        i = str(numLines) + '. ' + i
        numbered += i
        print (i)

        numLines += 1

    viewSelection = input('\n^ Avaiable Paths ^\nInput the preset\'s number you want to perform an action on.\n')

    for i in numbered:
        if viewSelection in i:
            viewAction = input('\nInput action for this preset.\nOptions: "Delete"')
            if viewAction.lower() == 'delete':
```

I simply want a way to delete a line by it's number in a file.

Comment: Instead of actually editing the original file, it's much easier to create a new file that has every line __except__ the one to be deleted, and then rename the file afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I haven't tried much. I updated the post with code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be to read the lines into a list, update the list, and write it back to the same file. Something like this:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    del lines[linenum]  # use linenum - 1 if linenum starts from 1
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(lines)
```