# os.system output to a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I would like that `NC_008934.1` is my key and `Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence` is my value`. Unfortunately, the below code is not working

**UPDATE:**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(
        ["find .  -name \"*.fna\" -exec  grep \">\" '{}' \; | cut -d '|' -f 4,5"],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE)
result, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise IOError(err)
names = result.strip()
#names has many of this strings NC_008934.1| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence

names_dict = {n[0] : n[1] for n in (nameline.split("|") for nameline in namelines)}
print "!!!", names_dict
```

**Error**

```
python mapped_ids_names.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapped_ids_names.py", line 6, in <module>
    stderr=PIPE)
  File "/work/water/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/work/water/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What did I miss?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Your last line does not seem syntactically correct.

Comment: File "mapped_ids_names.py", line 7
    names_dict = {(n[0]:n[1]) n.split("|") for n in names}
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You can't have just a space between your tuple and `n.split`. See my answer for a more syntactically correct `dict` generation code.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
nameline1 = "NC_008934.1| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence"
nameline2 = "NC_008934.2| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 2"
namelines = [nameline1, nameline2]
names_dict = {n[0] : n[1] for n in (nameline.split("|") for nameline in namelines)}
```

#### Edit

Based on your comments, it seems that the output of your `os.system` call is not what you think it is: You obtain the return code of your shell command, which is an int, and not its standard output. You may have more success using the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(
        ["find .  -name \"*.fna\" -exec  grep \">\" '{}' \; | cut -d '|' -f 4,5"],
        stdout=PIPE,
        stderr=PIPE,
        shell=True)
    result, err = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise IOError(err)
namelines = result.decode("utf-8").strip().split("\n")
```

To help you adapt this to your needs, see the following links:

- http://stackoverflow.com/a/845069/1878788
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

**Pay special attention to the warning about using `shell=True`** in the last link: Don't use this if the command line is not completely under your control.

Besides, you seem to be parsing fasta files. This can be done using various python libraries. You can see some of them tested here: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/380/292

Comment: I got Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapped_ids_names.py", line 7, in <module>
    names_dict = {n[0] : n[1] for n in (nameline.split("|") for nameline in names)}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapped_ids_names.py", line 6, in <module>
    stderr=PIPE)
  File "/work/water/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/work/water/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @user977828 Maybe you could update your question with the latest version of your code. This would make the current problem easier to understand.

Comment: My use of Popen is wrong, sorry. I'll try to correct that. Meanwhile, you can have a look at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline. You can look at `err` to get debugging clues.

Comment: The issue was that when a single string is passed and is composed of more than an executable name, `Popen` needs the `shell=True` option. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a string with `for n in names` you'll get each *character* in `names`, it seems you want to iterate over the *lines* of `names`, you can do this by using `splitlines()`.

Besides this, your last line isn't syntactically correct and you probably want to `strip()` the keys and values to remove any trailing or leading whitespace.

Try this:

```
names_dict = {pair[0].strip() : pair[1].strip() for pair in (line.split("|") for line in names.splitlines())}
```

It works for me:

```
In [1]: names = """NC_008934.1| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence
   ...: NC_008934.2| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 2
   ...: NC_008934.3| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 3
   ...: NC_008934.4| Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 4"""

In [2]: names_dict = {pair[0].strip() : pair[1].strip() for pair in (line.split("|") for line in names.splitlines())}

In [3]: names_dict
Out[3]: 
{'NC_008934.1': 'Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence',
 'NC_008934.2': 'Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 2',
 'NC_008934.3': 'Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 3',
 'NC_008934.4': 'Glypta fumiferanae ichnovirus segment B18, complete sequence 4'}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapped_ids_names.py", line 7, in <module>
    names_dict = {n[0].strip() : n[1].strip() for n in (nameline.split("|") for nameline in names.splitlines)}
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: It seems you've updated your question with a proper way to catch the output of your shell command, is it still not working?