# What is the fastest way to select n random lines from csv file to list?

Tags: python

I have the following method:

```
ids = random.sample(list(map(int, open(file_path))), 10)
```

that returns a list of 10 random ints.

How to speed up it? What is the other way to do this?

Comment: the way you do it, the whole file is loaded to memory and then sampled. The better way would be to only read specific but random lines.

Comment: It depends :) Imagine, the lines are the same length, for example. You can be very quick then :)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis How to do this?

Comment: A simple trick to speed it up (that does not solve the issue I mentioned above) is to leave the conversion to `int` for **after** the sampling. It does not make sense to convert **all** `str`ings to `int`egers from the get go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me that the hangup is always going to be finding the length of the file. See [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python) for that.

then you can do

```
import random

lines = random.sample(range(length_of_file), 10)

with open(file) as f:
    lines_from_file = [f.readline(line) for line in lines]
```

or something like that. How does that compare speedwise?