# Count the line number of file

Tags: python

I just want to count the file lines.

I have googoled around and found two ways but in vane

```
test = open('./log/test.csv','a')

if sum(1 for line in test) == 0:
    print("no line")
```

shows

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

second way

```
test = open('./log/test.csv','a')

if len(test.readlines()) == 0:
    print("no line")
```

it shows error too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: You are opening up the file in 'append'  mode. How are you expecting to read from it?

Answer (score 1):

try doing:

```
test = open('./log/test.csv', 'r')
```

The issue could be you don't have it on read mode

Comment: AH I see, I wanted to append the lines to this file, so I use `a` value and I thought `a` includes `r` function, now I open file once by `r` mode and then open again with 'a' mode to append lines

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `'a'` in your open function:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    print(len(list(enumerate(f))))
```