# Why is Python3 much slower than Python2 on my task?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, performance

I was surprised to know that `Python 3.5.2` is much slower than `Python 2.7.12`. I wrote a simple command line command that calculates the number of lines in a huge CSV-file.

```
$ cat huge.csv | python -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))"
101253515
# it took 15 seconds

$ cat huge.csv | python3 -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))"
101253515
# it took 66 seconds
```

Python 2.7.12 took 15 seconds, Python 3.5.2 took 66 seconds. I expected that the difference may take place, but why is it so huge? What's new in Python 3 that makes it much slower towards such kind of tasks? Is there a faster way to calculate the number of lines in Python 3?

My CPU is `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz`.

The size of `huge.csv` is 18.1 Gb and it contains 101253515 lines.

Asking this question, I don't need exactly to find the number of lines of a big file at any cost. I just wrote a particular case where Python 3 is much slower. Actually, I am developing a script in Python 3 that deals with big CSV files, some operations don't suppose of using `csv` library. I know, I could write the script in Python 2, and it would be acceptable towards the speed. But I would like to know a way to write similar script in Python 3. This is why I am interested what makes Python 3 slower in my example and how it can be improved by "honest" python approaches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python

Comment: @CoryKramer it doesn't explain the difference between python versions.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but why not use `wc` instead of Python?  `cat huge.csv | wc -l`, or `wc -l huge.csv`.

Comment: @mhawke Because I I want to make it as a piece of my python script.

Comment: Python3 architecture and datatypes are bigger/complexer and so i guess it´s something very special because python 2 and 3 are even, but python 3 get more and more performance updates - so I guess you can´t compare the same task on both versions. to it python 2 and 3 way or do benchmarks and compare them.

Comment: @mhawke By the way, `wc -l huge.csv` takes 15 seconds as Python 2.

Comment: @LenglBoy Thanks, but I don't intend to benchmark them. I need a fast way to process big CSV-files in Python 3 as it is in Python 2. Or to find out why it becomes impossible.

Comment: Maybe have a look here [consuming huge csv in python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88885/efficiently-filter-a-large-100gb-csv-file-v3)

Comment: You can analyse the execution by using a profiler:
`echo "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))" > linecount.py`
`cat huge.csv | python -m cProfile linecount.py`
This will show you which function how often gets called and what time it took. But I can't explain why it's taking much longer. I also tested it and it takes about 50% longer with pyhon 3.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: that doesn't sound right, `wc` should be _much_ faster, and it is when I test it on a 85M line file. Perhaps there is an I/O bottleneck. Also, I find Python 3 time comparable to Python 2.

Comment: @mhawke My file is much bigger. I updated my question. Please, have a look.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: What processing do you need to do with the CSV data? Do you need to hold the large chunks of the file in memory, or can you process line-by-line? Depends entirely on your application, but since you're not just counting lines, perhaps a database would be better than a flat file.

Comment: @mhawke I want to aggregate some data and to store the result into another file. It doesn't require to keep chunks in memory. As far as I see, the slowest place is reading from the source file.

Comment: @Fomalhaut: _Maybe_ `pandas` would be faster? Alternatively read the file once into a database. Add relevant indices. Query using aggregate functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.stdin` object is a bit more complicated in Python3 then it was in Python2. For example by default reading from `sys.stdin` in Python3 converts the input into unicode, thus it fails on non-unicode bytes:

```
$ echo -e "\xf8" | python3 -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <genexpr>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Note that Python2 doesn't have any problem with that input. So as you can see Python3's `sys.stdin` does more things under the hood. I'm not sure if this is exactly responsible for the performance loss but you can investigate it further by trying `sys.stdin.buffer` under Python3:

```
import sys
print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin.buffer))
```

Note that `.buffer` doesn't exist in Python2. I've done some tests and I don't see real difference in performance between Python2's `sys.stdin` and Python3's `sys.stdin.buffer` but YMMV.

**EDIT** Here are some random results on my machine: ubuntu 16.04, i7 cpu, 8GiB RAM. First some C code (as a base for comparison):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char buffer[4096];
    size_t total = 0;
    while (true) {
        int result = ::read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        total += result;
        if (result == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

now the file size:

```
$ ls -s --block-size=M | grep huge2.txt 
10898M huge2.txt
```

and tests:

```
// a.out is a simple C equivalent code (except for the final print)
$ time cat huge2.txt | ./a.out

real    0m20.607s
user    0m0.236s
sys     0m10.600s


$ time cat huge2.txt | python -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))"
898773889

real    1m24.268s
user    1m20.216s
sys     0m8.724s


$ time cat huge2.txt | python3 -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin.buffer))"
898773889

real    1m19.734s
user    1m14.432s
sys     0m11.940s


$ time cat huge2.txt | python3 -c "import sys; print(sum(1 for _ in sys.stdin))"
898773889

real    2m0.326s
user    1m56.148s
sys     0m9.876s
```

So the file I've used was a bit smaller and times were longer ( it seems that you have a better machine and I didn't have patience for larger files :D ). Anyway Python2 and Python3's `sys.stdin.buffer` are quite similar in my tests. Python3's `sys.stdin` is way slower. And all of them are waaaay behind the C code (which has almost 0 user time).

Comment: Thanks. I checked it takes `23 seconds`, that's much faster than without `.buffer`. But it's 1.5 times slower than Python 2.

Comment: @Fomalhaut Did you do multiple tests and took average? You read from disk and pipe it to a process. When I run this code on my machine the results vary: one time python2 is faster and second time python3. This is due to the noise generated by the OS (and other processes). But on average they were quite close (Python2 a bit faster, something like 2-3%, not much). If they are not in your case then I suppose this is how it is: in your setup Python3 is just slower.

Comment: I measured the consumed time carefully, multiple times, taking average, of course. Probably, you're right, my Python 2 setup is slower. I think 15 and 23 seconds are comparable.

Comment: @freakish That doesn't count the number of lines, that just counts the size. You'd have to for loop over the buffer and count '\n'. I'd edit your answer but it has a benchmark so I can't (As it'll affect the output). It's probably better benchmarking to include a final printf so it's actually input/output identical to the python, and so you would've noticed the logic error.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone why would I want to count number of lines? OP's code doesn't do that.