# How to write multiple lines with a varying number in each line?

Tags: python, text, file-writing

I've been trying to create a text file using python in which I must write around 200 lines. Each line contains the same string but it contains a number that ranges from 1901 to 2100. For example,

```
this_is_the_string_with_a_number_xxxx_in_each_line
```

where xxxx varies from 1901 to 2100 (in the ascending order itself). How do I write these lines to a txt file using python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get line count cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: @zakharuk_pasha how is it duplicate? :/

Answer (score 2):

this should do the work:

```
with open("my_file.txt", "w") as myfile:
   stub_string = "this_is_the_string_with_a_number_%s_in_each_line\n"
   for number in range(1901, 2100):
      string_with_number = stub_string % number
      myfile.write(string_with_number)
```

Comment: side note: `range(1901, 2100)` loops to 2099. If you want to include 2100 as well, just change it to `range(1901, 2101)`