# Python: How do I split a .txt file into two or more files with the same number of lines in each?

Tags: python, file

(I believe I have been looking for hours on stackexchange's and the internet, but couldn't find the right answer)

What I'm trying to do here is to count the number of lines a file has, I achieved that with this code here

```
# Does not loud into memory
def file_len(fname):
with open(fname) as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
        pass
    print(i)

file_len('bigdata.txt')
```

then I take the number of lines of the file and divide it by two/three/etc (to make two/three/etc files with the same amount of lines) e.g. bigdata.txt = 1000000 lines
1000000/2=500000 So here I will have two files with a 500000 lines in each, one starting from 1 to 500000 & the other from 500001 to 1000000.
I already have this code which looks for a pattern in the original file(bigdata.txt), but I'm not looking for any pattern, just want to split the thing into two halfs or whatsover. Here is the code for it:

```
# Does not loud into memory
with open('bigdata.txt', 'r') as r:
with open('fhalf', 'w') as f:
    for line in r:
        if line == 'pattern\n': # Splits the file when there is an occurence of the pattern.
#But the occurence as you may notice won't be included in either the two files which is not a good thing since I need all the data.
            break
                f.write(line)
with open('shalf.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in r:
        f.write(line)
```

So I'm looking for a simple solution and I know there is one, just can't figure it out for this moment.
sample would be: file1.txt , file2.txt each with the same number lines give or take one.
**Thank you all for your time.**

Comment: Just by the looks of it, your first function can't be right. Python is a zero-indexed language, so you'll need to `+1` that `i`.

Comment: Yes, you' re correct, that's my first solution too, then I ditched the +1 .This was my first solution: def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in all the lines to a list with `.readlines()` and then calculate how many lines need to be distributed to each file and then get writing!

```
num_files = 2
with open('bigdata.txt') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()
    lines_per_file = len(lines) // num_files
    for n in range(num_files):
        with open('file{}.txt'.format(n+1), 'w') as out_file:
            for i in range(n * lines_per_file, (n+1) * lines_per_file):
                out_file.write(lines[i])
```

And a full test:

```
$ cat bigdata.txt 
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
$ python -q
>>> num_files = 2
>>> with open('bigdata.txt') as in_file:
...     lines = in_file.readlines()
...     lines_per_file = len(lines) // num_files
...     for n in range(num_files):
...         with open('file{}.txt'.format(n+1), 'w') as out_file:
...             for i in range(n * lines_per_file, (n+1) * lines_per_file):
...                 out_file.write(lines[i])
... 
>>> 
$ more file*
::::::::::::::
file1.txt
::::::::::::::
line1
line2
line3
::::::::::::::
file2.txt
::::::::::::::
line4
line5
line6
```

---

If you can't read `bigdata.txt` into memory then the `.readlines()` solution won't cut it.

You will have to write the lines as you read them which is no big deal.

As for working out the length in the first place, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python) discusses some methods, my favourite being Kyle's `sum()` method.

```
num_files = 2
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('bigdata.txt'))
lines_per_file = num_lines // num_files
with open('bigdata.txt') as in_file:
    for n in range(num_files):
        with open('file{}.txt'.format(n+1), 'w') as out_file:
            for _ in range(lines_per_file):
                out_file.write(in_file.readline())
```

Comment: The whole point of `file_len` is that you can count the lines without reading the file in memory. Useful for huge files. Assuming that's the reason OP chose this `file_len` implementation, your solution will not be suitable. Fine answer if memory is not an issue though.

Comment: Yeah, I deliberately used the file_len since I'm dealing with +10000000 lines, so I needed to avoid reading that in memory.

Comment: @MurphyAdam See my updated answer. It does not read the whole file into memory, just one line at a time

Comment: @Joe Idoon. Thank you Mr, your code does the job ^^

Comment: @Joe Idoon, My bad XD. Thanks again.

Comment: @MurphyAdam No problem