# Speed up read large file in parallel using Python

Tags: python

I need to process two large files (> 1 billion lines) and split each file into small files based on the information in specific lines in one file. 
The files record high throughput sequencing data in `blocks` (we say sequencing `reads`), while each `read` contains 4 lines, (`name`, `sequence`, `n`, `quality`). The `read` records are in the same order in two files.

**to-do**

split `file1.fq` based on the `id` field in `file2.fq`,

The two files looks like this:

```
$ head -n 4 file1.fq
@name1_1
ACTGAAGCGCTACGTCAT
+
A#AAFJJJJJJJJFJFFF

$ head -n 4 file2.fq
@name1_2
TCTCCACCAACAACAGTG
+
FJJFJJJJJJJJJJJAJJ
```

I wrote the following python function to do this job:

```
def p7_bc_demx_pe(fn1, fn2, id_dict):
    """Demultiplex PE reads, by p7 index and barcode"""
    # prepare writers for each small files
    fn_writer = {}
    for i in id_dict:
        fn_writer[i] = [open(id_dict[i] + '.1.fq', 'wt'),
            open(id_dict[i] + '.2.fq', 'wt')]

    # go through each record in two files
    with open(fn1, 'rt') as f1, open(fn2, 'rt') as f2:
        while True:
            try:
                s1 = [next(f1), next(f1), next(f1), next(f1)]
                s2 = [next(f2), next(f2), next(f2), next(f2)]
                tag = func(s2) # a function to classify the record
                fn_writer[tag][0].write(''.join(s1))
                fn_writer[tag][1].write(''.join(s2))
            except StopIteration:
                break
    # close writers
    for tag in p7_bc_writer: 
        fn_writer[tag][0].close() # close writers
        fn_writer[tag][1].close() # close writers
```

**Question**

Is there any way to speed up this process? (above function is much too slow)

How about split large file into chunks with specific `lines` (like f.seek()), and run the process in parallel with multiple cores?

**EDIT-1**

A total of 500 Million reads in each file (~180 GB in size). The bottleneck is `reading and writing` file. The following is my current solution (it works, but definitely not the best)

I first split the big file into smaller files using shell command: `split -l` (takes ~3 hours).

Then, apply the functions to 8 small files in parallel (takes ~1 hours)

Finally, merge the results (takes ~ 2 hours)

> not trying PySpark yet, thanks @John H

Comment: If the bottleneck of your program is in reading and writing to files, parallelizing it will not make it much faster unless your hardware support parallel operations (e.g. RAID).

Comment: Yes, I think it is about reading and writing. Do you have any suggestions for this mission? right now, I split the large files into small files first, and process each small file separately in parallel.

Comment: If you've got the resources, try copying the files to `/dev/shm`, perhaps?

Comment: I wrote an example of using the multiprocessing module to count lines in a large file.  It may offer you some ideas for splitting up the work.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-cheaply-in-python/6826326#6826326

Answer (score 1):

Look into Spark. You can spread your file across a cluster for much faster processing. There is a python API: pyspark.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html

This also gives you the advantage of actually executing Java code, which doesn't suffer from the GIL and allowing for true multi-threading.