# Select every nth row as a Pandas DataFrame without reading the entire file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am reading a large file that contains ~9.5 million rows x 16 cols.

I am interested in retrieving a representative sample, and since the data is organized by time, I want to do this by selecting every 500th element.

I am able to load the data, and then select every 500th row.

My question: Can I immediately read every 500th element (using.pd.read_csv() or some other method), without having to read first and then filter my data?

Question 2: How would you approach this problem if the date column was not ordered? At the moment, I am assuming it's ordered by date, but all data is prone to errors.

Here is a snippet of what the data looks like (first five rows) The first 4 rows are out of order, bu the remaining dataset looks ordered (by time):

```
VendorID    tpep_pickup_datetime    tpep_dropoff_datetime   passenger_count trip_distance   RatecodeID  store_and_fwd_flag  PULocationID    DOLocationID    payment_type    fare_amount extra   mta_tax tip_amount  tolls_amount    improvement_surcharge   total_amount
0   1   2017-01-09 11:13:28 2017-01-09 11:25:45 1   3.30    1   N   263 161 1   12.5    0.0 0.5 2.00    0.00    0.3 15.30
1   1   2017-01-09 11:32:27 2017-01-09 11:36:01 1   0.90    1   N   186 234 1   5.0 0.0 0.5 1.45    0.00    0.3 7.25
2   1   2017-01-09 11:38:20 2017-01-09 11:42:05 1   1.10    1   N   164 161 1   5.5 0.0 0.5 1.00    0.00    0.3 7.30
3   1   2017-01-09 11:52:13 2017-01-09 11:57:36 1   1.10    1   N   236 75  1   6.0 0.0 0.5 1.70    0.00    0.3 8.50
4   2   2017-01-01 00:00:00 2017-01-01 00:00:00 1   0.02    2   N   249 234 2   52.0    0.0 0.5 0.00    0.00    0.3 52.80
```

Comment: For the first question, I believe the `skiprows` argument of read_csv will come handy

Comment: `pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=lambda i: i % n)`

Answer (score 10):

> Can I immediately **read every 500th element** (using.pd.read_csv() or some other method), without having to read first and then filter my data?

Something you could do is to use the `skiprows` parameter in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which accepts a list-like argument to discard the rows of interest (and thus, also select). So you could create a [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with a length equal to the amount of rows to read, and remove every `500th` element from it using [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), so *this way we'll only be reading every 500th row*:

```
n_rows = 9.5e6
skip = np.arange(n_rows)
skip = np.delete(skip, np.arange(0, n_rows, 500))
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', skiprows = skip)
```

Comment: quite useful. To reduce the amount of records by less than one half, the deletion step could occur more than once

Comment: np.delete() generated an error when I tried to execute the code: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Answer (score 3):

> Can I immediately read every 500th element (using.pd.read_csv() or some other method), without having to read first and then filter my data?

First get the length of the file by a custom function, remove each 500 row by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) and pass to the `skiprows` parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/q/845058
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

len_of_file = file_len('test.csv')
print (len_of_file)

skipped = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len_of_file), np.arange(0,len_of_file,500))
print (skipped)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=skipped)
```

> How would you approach this problem if the date column was not ordered? At the moment, I am assuming it's ordered by date, but all data is prone to errors.

The idea is read only the `datetime` column by parameter `usecols`, and then sort and select each 500 index value, get the difference and pass again to parameter `skiprows`:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

len_of_file = file_len('test.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',
                  usecols=['tpep_pickup_datetime'],
                  parse_dates=['tpep_pickup_datetime'])

sorted_idx = (df1['tpep_pickup_datetime'].sort_values()
                 .iloc[np.arange(0,len_of_file,500)].index)

skipped = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len_of_file), sorted_idx)
print (skipped)

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=skipped).sort_values(by=['tpep_pickup_datetime'])
```

Answer (score 2):

use a lambda with `skiprows`:

```
pd.read_csv(path, skiprows=lambda i: i % N)
```

to skip every `N` rows.

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module return a iterator and use `itertools.cycle` to select every nth row.

```py
import csv
from itertools import cycle

source_file='D:/a.txt'
cycle_size=500
chooser = (x == 0 for x in cycle(range(cycle_size))) 
with open(source_file) as f1:
    rdr = csv.reader(f1) 
    data = [row for pick, row in zip(chooser, rdr) if pick]
```