# Iterating specific characters through an input data file

Tags: python

I am creating a program that will take user input and read a txt file to `print` number of *lines, vowels, and numeric characters* within it, repeating until the user does not want to execute it again. I am able to get the correct `print` for *lines*, however I am getting 0 for *vowels and numeric characters*. I believe that Python counts the strings line by line using the `open` function but requires the `.read()` function to iterate through individual characters. As such, I have assigned `char` as the variable for that iteration.

```
def txtcount():
    count = 0
    vowels = 0
    numerical = 0
    fname = input('Please enter file name: ')
    fopen = open(fname)
    for line in fopen:
        count +=1
    char = fopen.read()
    for number in char:
        if number.isnumeric():
            numerical = int(number) + 1
    for vwl in char:
        if vwl.isalpha():
            if vwl is 'a' 'A' 'e' 'E' 'i' 'I' 'o' 'O' 'u' 'U' 'y' 'Y' :
                vowels += int(vwl) + 1
            else :
                vowels = int(vwl) + 0 
    print('File',fname,'has', count, 'lines.')
    print('File',fname,'has', vowels, 'vowels')
    print('File',fname,'has', numerical, 'numerical characters\n')
    
    

while True:
    txtcount()
    tryagain = input('Do you want to try again? (y or n)').lower()
    if tryagain == 'y' :
        continue
    if tryagain == 'n' :
         break
print('Thanks for playing!')
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `if vwl is 'a' 'A' 'e' 'E' 'i' 'I' 'o' 'O' 'u' 'U' 'y' 'Y' :` to mean? How and why?

Comment: There are multiple issues I see with the code, but the most important ones both happen to be common issues with established reference/duplicate answers. The problem occurs because `char` is empty (since you have already read the file with the `for line` loop), and after that you will need proper logic for the vowel membership test. After that, the remaining problem is that your tallying logic for the vowels and digits is incorrect - you want to count them the same way you count the lines. None of that stuff with `int()` makes any sense.

Comment: "I believe that Python counts the strings line by line using the open function but requires the .read() function to iterate through individual characters." This description, however, is a mess. Getting code right requires clear thinking, and it helps to start with accurate use of terminology. For example, Python doesn't "count" anything; the program logic counts the lines, by doing `count += 1`, `for` each of the `line`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `python`'s built in `re` package for handling regular expressions.

First, I'll define functions to count the number of vowels and numbers in a given string:

```py
import re

def find_vowels(text):
    pattern = re.compile("[aeiouAEIOU]")
    results = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return len(results)

def find_numeric(text):
    pattern = re.compile("[0-9]")
    results = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return len(results)
```

This code defines regular expression patterns that are then matched to the text. Each match is returned as part of a list, and I then return the length of that list as the value that you're looking for.

Now I can define another function that uses user input to open a text file and go through it line by line, counting lines, vowels, and numbers as it goes with the help of our previously defined functions:

```py
def txtcount():
    vowel_count = 0
    numeric_count = 0
    fname = input('Please enter file name: ')
    with open(fname) as file:
        for i, l in enumerate(file):
            vowel_count += find_vowels(l)
            numeric_count += find_numeric(l)
    print("Lines: {}\nVowels: {}\nNumbers: {}".format(i+1, vowel_count, numeric_count))
```

I wrote this scintillating piece of literature to test my code:

```
I am a text file
I have a whole bunch of lines
1, 2, 3, count how many!
```

When I put `txtcount()` at the end of my code and run it in the command line I get the following output:

```
Lines: 3
Vowels: 20
Numbers: 3
```

I am indebted to [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python) for my approach to getting the line count in an efficient manner.

Also, it's well worthwhile to read the `python` docs on `re` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).