# How to get a line count of a file in Python

Tags: python, string, loops, file, command-prompt

I am trying to get a line count of a file using command prompt. However when I execute the code I get the output of 0.

```
import sys
file = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
lines=0
line=file.readline()
while line !="":
  lines=lines+1
  line=file.readline()
print("Lines:"+str(lines)+"\n")
file.close()
```

This code works perfectly fine, the lines inside the file was deleted.And that caused the output of 0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get line count of a large file cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: The code works, but [as the OP mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868567/how-to-get-a-line-count-of-a-file-in-python#comment114688506_64868694), the "*lines inside the data is deleted*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file, "r") as f:
    num_lines = len(f.readlines())
```

Comment: It returns me a value of 0

Comment: Double check your file and that your script picks up the right argument from argv.

Comment: Thank you! You were right I found out that the lines inside the data is deleted.

Comment: Sometimes it's the stupidest things that trip you up. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `readlines` not `readline`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
file = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
line_count = len(lines)
print(f"There are {line_count} lines")
```

Comment: I get 0 when I use this code

Answer (score 0):

to get your line count, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python):

```
import sys, os

def file_len(fname):
    if os.stat(file_path).st_size == 0:
        print('File is empty')
        return 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

print(file_len(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: no :( good catch

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me if I run it as `python myscript.py myfile.txt`, using Python 3.8.5 on MacOS.

However the script could be cleaned up a little. It would be a good idea to use Python's `open()` context handler while reading the file, the `readlines()` method to get all the lines at once, and Python's built-in tools for string formatting. Then you can do the whole count very simply like this:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    lines = len(file.readlines())
print(f"Lines: {lines}\n")
```

You may also want to consider using Python's `argparse` module to handle your argument(s).

Comment: It gives me the following error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Yeah, I was mistaken about the order of arguments in an early version of this answer. Turns out your code runs fine for me as-is. Are you sure you're not specifying an empty file?