# Pandas only reading first, next-to-last and last row of text file

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, indexing

Since I only need the rows with indices 0, -2 & -1 from a txt file and want to optimize the code for speed (the text files I'll be working with will become quite long at some point), I wanted to ask if someone knows if it is possible to avoid loading the whole file and just load the needed rows. I came across the following code which I thought would be the perfect solution to this problem:

```
rows_wanted = [0,-2,-1]    
data = pd.read_csv(txt_path, skiprows = lambda x: x not in rows_wanted)
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if this does not work with negative indices since the output only contains the first row. Therefore, I thought to just calculate the positive index values corresponding to -2 & -1 by obtaining the overall amount of rows in the file but I haven't found a solution which itself does not require to load the whole file. I also came across the head and tail methods of Pandas but as far as I've understood these would also only become useful after loading the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `pd.rad_csv` has a good way of doing what you want natively. One option is to use the answers for [how to efficiently get line count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-the-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python), and use that in your code

```
# file_name = 'myfile.csv'
num_lines = sum(1 for _ in open(file_name))

rows_wanted = [x if x>= 0 else num_lines + x for x in rows_wanted]
pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', skiprows= lambda x: x not in rows_wanted)
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized way for large files is to open the file in *binary* mode, then move the file pointer starting at the end with [`f.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek), detect 2 linebreaks `b'\n'` (denoting respective last 2 lines) and read the lines as [`io.BinaryIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) into a dataframe.

Sample:

```
import os
import io

fname = 'test.csv'

with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
    head = f.readline() # read the 1st line (head)
    f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END) # forward file pointer 2 bytes from the end
    n = 2

    while n:
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR) # move file pointer backward
        if f.read(1) == b'\n': # catch a linebreak
            n -= 1

    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(head + f.read()))
```

Comment: What if the CSV file contains UTF-8 text? What if some quoted text field contains a newline? It may be unavoidable to use `csv` to get a proper parser, yet an iterable one (no need to store the whole file).

Answer (score 0):

One way that respects text encoding and possible quoted newlines, etc. is to use `csv` and a `deque` to store the "last n" rows:

```py
import csv
from collections import deque

def row_selector_gen(file, rows, **fmtargs):
    buflen = max(1, 1 - min(rows))
    buflines = deque(maxlen=buflen)
    reader = csv.reader(file, **fmtargs)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i in rows:
            yield row
            buflines.append(None)
        else:
            buflines.append(row)
    for i in sorted([i for i in rows if i < 0]):
        try:
            row = buflines[i]
            if row is not None:
                yield row
        except IndexError:
            pass

def row_selector(file, rows, **fmtargs):
    buf = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buf, **fmtargs)
    writer.writerows(row_selector_gen(file, rows, **fmtargs))
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf
```

Example:

```py
# 1. setup

content = """foo,bar,garçon
1,0.1,"this
and that"
2,0.2,x
3,0.3,y
4,0.4,z
5,0.5,"ha
ha"
"""

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

Then:

```py
with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
    z = pd.read_csv(row_selector(f, [0, 1, -2, -1]))

>>> z
   foo  bar          garçon
0    1  0.1  this\nand that
1    4  0.4               z
2    5  0.5          ha\nha
```

**Limitations:**

- You may get rows out of order, for example if you intermingle positive and negative indices in `rows`, or if some negative indices refer to rows before some of the positive ones. For example, with the `test.csv` above:

  ```py
  with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
      z = pd.read_csv(row_selector(f, [0, 3, -4, -1]))

  >>> z
     foo  bar  garçon
  0    3  0.3       y
  1    2  0.2       x
  2    5  0.5  ha\nha
  ```
- If you specify a negative row that is earlier than the start of the file, they are silently skipped:

  ```py
  with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
      z = pd.read_csv(row_selector(f, [0, 3, -14, -1]))

  >>> z
     foo  bar  garçon
  0    3  0.3       y
  1    5  0.5  ha\nha
  ```