# tailf for windows

Tags: windows, tail

I found tail2win but it is a paid product. Are there any good freeware or shareware out there?

Comment: what exactly are you asking for? I couldn't find anything googling 'tail2win'. Should it be like 'tail' unix command?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows for lists of unix tools for windows

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a unix-style `tail` or `tail -f` then you can get the real thing from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).  Cygwin is a port of many unix commands to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Try [BareTail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/). There's a free version and a pay-for version. The free version shows an extra splash screen on startup, but is otherwise fully functional.

A small extract from the feature list:

- View the end of a growing file in real time, no matter how fast the file grows
- Like "tail -f" on Unix systems, but with many more features

Answer (score 2):

go to [GNU win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) and download coreutils etc. you will find `tail` command. It free.

Comment: +1 This is one of the first things I always install on computers I will use frequently.

Answer (score 0):

http://infiero.com/tailxp/

Answer (score 0):

Even on unix i quite like this perl module for tailing:

http://metacpan.org/pod/File::Tail

Mainly because it detects when a file is replaced, which normal tail doesn't cope with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://wintailviewer.leosis.kinghost.net/
I like it because it's free and there are a lot of features: top most windows, multiple files, window opacity. It's fantastic to see apache logs while you refresh your localhost page.

Comment: Is this your product? (I ask because your username is Leo and the link contains "Leo" in it.) If I'm wrong, my apologies. If you are indeed affiliated with the product, you are required to disclose that affiliation in your posts, and a majority of your contributions should not be about products you are affiliated with. Thanks! :)