# Clearcase: List labels matching a particular string

Tags: clearcase

I would like to list the available labels matching a particular string applied in the view.

Answer (score 4):

I confirm a filter in [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) is not possible:

```
 ct find . -ele "lbtype_sub(My_LAB*)" -print
```

would not work (no [wildcard](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/wildcards_ccase.htm) in [query argument](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm).

If you cannot use a grep in a shell pipe, can you consider using grep in an exec part of a find, [like in this example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=151235)?

```
ct find . -kind lbtype -exec "echo %CLEARCASE_PN%|grep MY_LAB"
```

If this is not acceptable, you need to write the result in a file and process it with another tool (sed?)

You have packages for Windows including Unix commands: see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows).
Of you have [freeware emulating the grep command](http://pages.interlog.com/~tcharron/grep.html).

If you must stay with *native* Windows commands, you must redirect the result in a file, [and use FIND](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep#.C3.89quivalent_de_grep_sous_Windows_:_la_commande_find) ([English translation](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.fr&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhiDMfSeevD8irmIWDfw3e6-9dEHoQ#.C3.89quivalent_de_grep_sous_Windows_:_la_commande_find)).

Comment: Thanks , this is running on windows , hence was in need of excluding the grep.

Comment: @Raj: you can install packages including Unix-like command on Windows: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I'm not entirely sure about this although the following will list all labels used for a given VOB (entered using ClearTool command line application).

```
lstype -kind lbtype -invob vob_path_and_name -short
```

for example with a View mapped to drive U: VOB "Some_VOB" would be:

```
lstype -kind lbtype -invob U:\Some_VOB -short
```

Comment: True, but need to filter based on the string passed.
I can easily do it using the grep , but the limitation is that grep should not be used. Hence the only option left is to use the cleartool find command . Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that a wildcard can be used here, I was going to suggest a Perl script and then grep the results, but you say that you can't use grep. I'll have to think further.