# cleartool: How to list all labels in a stream chronologically?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I want to list all the labels applied to a stream in a chronological order. Ideally, I would like one like the following for each label:

```
 <label> <timestamp> <userid>
```

I looked at few questions. The command

```
 ct lstype -kind lbtype -invob . -short
```

from the question "[Clearcase: List labels matching a particular string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342166/clearcase-list-labels-matching-a-particular-string)" appeared promising, but it lists the labels that were applied in the ancestor streams. I do not want that, I want only the labels that are applied to the current stream.

I feel that there must be some way, but unfortunately I could not find out. If you have suggestions, I can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mentioning Stream, that means ClearCase UCM, which includes UCM Baselines.

You need to reason with baselines, not labels: a baseline can be an incremental one, which means you won't find a label for *all* elements of a given component.
(See "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696598/what-is-the-difference-between-full-baseline-and-incremental-baseline-in-clearca/9696988#9696988)" for more).
Lbtypes and labels are attached ("guarded") to baselines (through an hyperlink), but the actual object (associated with a userId and a date) are baselines.

```
cleartool lsbl -stream aStream@\aPVob
```

That will list all the baselines, from the oldest to the newest, applied on a given stream.
(see [`cleartool man lsbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsbl.htm))

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035841/cleartool-how-to-list-all-labels-in-a-stream-chronologically/13036581?noredirect=1#comment56928139_13036581) by [danger89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518879/danger89), `cleartool lsbl -s -stream aStream@\aPVob` would display 
a short version per line.

---

[danger89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518879/danger89) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035841/cleartool-how-to-list-all-labels-in-a-stream-chronologically/13036581?noredirect=1#comment82020402_13036581):

> To get a nice table output use:

```
(printf "Baseline|Label Status|Promotion Level|Owner|Predecessor baseline\n" \ ; cleartool lsbl -lev BUILT -fmt "%n|%[label_status]p|%[plevel]p|%[owner]p|%[predecessor]p\n" ) | column -t -s '|'
```

In multiple lines for readability:

```
(printf "Baseline|Label Status|Promotion Level|Owner|Predecessor baseline\n" \ ; 
 cleartool lsbl -lev BUILT -fmt "%n|%[label_status]p|%[plevel]p|%[owner]p|%[predecessor]p\n" )
   | column -t -s '|'
```

Comment: use ```ct lsbl -s``` to get a short version.

Comment: @danger89 True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: To get a nice table output use: `(printf "Baseline|Label Status|Promotion Level|Owner|Predecessor baseline\n" \
        ; cleartool lsbl -lev BUILT -fmt "%n|%[label_status]p|%[plevel]p|%[owner]p|%[predecessor]p\n" ) | column -t -s '|'` Yeeeh :D !

Comment: @danger89 Nice! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Again.