# clearcase ucm to git

Tags: git, github, clearcase-ucm

I have a requirement to migrate a UCM VOB with multiple components to GitHub.

I have read many such questions and answers and I am also convinced that migrating all history is not worth the effort.

But, I still have been asked to do so. How do I go about it?
Or rather: where to start from where I could capture at least some meaningful history?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearcase-ucm+git

Comment: @phd More precisely, I wrote *all* the answers to those "many questions". The most recent one is a good illustration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930287/6309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rules for an UCM import is:

- one Git repo per UCM component
- one main Git repo referencing [those sub-repos as submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Then:

- Pick a stream.
- For each component, [list their baselines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036581/6309).
- for each baseline, set your config spec and add its content to a Git repo, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930287/6309).

If your stream manages multiple component, and has set composite baselines (a baseline referencing other baselines), you can put a tag on the main repo (the one which refers the other git repos as submodules): that will help keep multiple Git repos history together.

The point is: only an UCM baseline is part of a meaningful history, as it represent a group of files in a coherent state (version), all labelled together.

Comment: thank you. exactly as you mentioned, my stream manages multiple components with composite baselines and also components are not independent as they refer to others as well . so we can achieve this using git submodules?

Comment: @user2636464 Yes, provides that your stream has set some compite baselines, which will help settings the components (in that stream) to a coherent state (ie: their content at the time of said composite baseline)

Comment: Thank you VonC for all the help for all these time. Really appreciated

Comment: for each baseline, set your config spec and add its content to a Git repo, as shown here.---- FOR UCM view, do you want to modify the config spec here for each baseline  100times as i have 100 baselines?

Comment: do you mean that I load one component at a time into a snapshot view and go through 100 times thought 100 baselines and commit 100 times into git repo for each baseline with my own commit message? sorry I am a bit lost here

Comment: @user2636464 you would be using a *dynamic* view for that, where you can rebase the baseline you need. A script will do so, baseline after baseline, in order for the dynamic view workspace to reflect the component contents to import to their respective Git repo (again: everything can be scripted).

Comment: so I have no original history imported here?  I am creating a commit for each baseline for the particular stream with my own comments.

Comment: @user2636464 yes, you need to import only the version labelled by baselines, not *all* version of *all* files.

Comment: @user2636464 Is there anything missing to this answer?

Comment: The last one if possible can you give a complete idea as I have started working on this and I have a main repo and 5 sub repos for each component as I am using composite baseline . I have a integration stream which has all the baselines. How can I iterate though and import the baselines to git repos ?

Comment: @user2636464 By listing the composite baselines (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036581/6309) and rebasing a dummy stream which each one, one after the other, in order to do your import.