# system2 command not found

Tags: r, system2

I am trying to count the number of words in a twitter file using the expression

```
system2("wc", args = "-w final/en_US/en_US.news.txt",stdout=TRUE)
```

I keep getting a message that

> Error in system2("wc", args = "-w final/en_US/en_US.news.txt", stdout
>   = TRUE) :    '"wc"' not found

I have tried all I could. I am not able to figure out what I may be doing wrong.

Any help\direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It's telling you that it can't find the `wc` command can't be found in the environment it's evaluating in. What OS are you using? This should work on OS X and Linux.

Comment: I am using WIndows 7

Comment: [Do you know a similar program for wc (unix word count command) on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows)