# how to count number of objects in a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I try to use the `stat` command in `gsutil` like this:

```
$ gsutil -q stat gs://test
```

but it resulted in the following exception:

> CommandException: The stat command only works with object URLs

Note: I don't want to use the `ls` command because there are too many files in the bucket.

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

`stat` only gives details of [objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat), not buckets and their total of files.

So, your best shot would be using [`du`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/du) in combination with `wc`:

```
$ gsutil du gs://your-bucket | wc -l
```

If you are running on Windows, check either [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows) or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/959036/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wc-l) for the `wc` command.

Comment: Thank you! But the command line show message:  'wc' is not an internal or external command, nor is it a runnable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to have `wc` installed, it's external to `gsutil` or `gcloud`. It looks, by your message error, that you are running on Windows. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247234/do-you-know-a-similar-program-for-wc-unix-word-count-command-on-windows) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/959036/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wc-l)

Comment: Yes, I am running on windows. I got it now, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. I will edit the answer to include the Windows bit. If you don't mind, please do accept the answer.

Comment: The question asked how to count the number of objects in a bucket.
gsutil du will report the number of bytes.

Comment: You can also count the number of objects with du and wc. The OP explicitly mentioned not using ls.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that my answer was wrong @MikeSchwartz : it counts the folders, where as yours doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of objects using:

```
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket/** | wc -l
```

Adding the `-l` flag will only display the number of objects.