# Copy the content of last line from text file and paste in excel column

Tags: excel, batch-file, text, copy

I wanted to write a batch file for following scenario:

I have multiple text file like 1.txt,2.txt...n.txt.
Now I want to copy the last line from text file and paste it in specified excel sheet colunm like coln B or H.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [BAT file to read and copy bottom 16 lines from a text file to another one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632300/bat-file-to-read-and-copy-bottom-16-lines-from-a-text-file-to-another-one)

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file? It could be easier with a VBS Script, I have no idea how to paste something in an excel file only with batch...

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript you can do it like this:

1. Create your excel file

   ```
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
   ```
2. Go through your text files in a loop, open them and read the last line

   ```
   Set n = 10 'the number of your files
   For i = 0 To n 

       Const ForReading = 1

       Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(i & ".txt", ForReading)

       Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
           strLine = objFile.ReadLine
       Loop

       objFile.Close
   ```
3. Write the data stored in `strLine` to your excel file

   ```
       objExcel.Application.Visible = True
       objExcel.Workbooks.Add
       objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = strLine

   Next
   ```
4. Save and close your excel file

   ```
   objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save "C:\test.xls"
   objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

   objExcel.Application.Quit
   ```

I have not tested this code, it should just show you an idea how it could possibly work.

Comment: i tried to run, but its displaying error at line 3 as "Object required : ['number:10]'. Any help?? Thanks