# Batchfile: read last lines from logfiles and copy them to a new file

Tags: batch-file

This is my first posting so if the format is not as it supposed to be please excuse me for this. (Suggestions for

improvement are welcome.)

I am trying to create a batchfile that will read last lines from logfiles and copy them to a new file.

Until now I have found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632300/bat-file-to-read-and-copy-bottom-16-lines-from-a-text-file-to-another-one) a way to read the last line.

Code would be something like:

```
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< someFile.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines% - 1
more /e +%startLine% someFile.txt > lastLines.txt
```

The above code works for one file at a time. What I need is to read the last line from all files in a known list and add this line to a new .csv file.

I have been using the following code for getting the 4th entry in the logfiles but it returns every line of every logfile:

```
for /f %%x in (%list%) do for /f "delims=.txt,  tokens=4" %%i in (%%x.txt) do echo %%x, %%i >> output.csv
```

What I would need is a sort of combination of both but I don't know how to combine them and make the complete last line be copied to the .csv file.

===
@Magoo:
Thanx for your reaction.
In every logfile can be 1 to >100 lines with comma separated information. Something like:

```
"LOGON,6-1-2015,12:43:39,USERNAME,HOSTNAME,,,,192.168.209.242,00:21:5A:2E:64:5E"
```

The last code with the 4th entry was used to get a list of all accounts that had logged in to the computers. This code gave me a very large list of all logon/logoff events on all computerlogs I checked in %list%. 
In %list$ I had all the names of logfiles I wanted to be checked. This returned all lines.

For a new batchfile I need only the last logon/logoff entry and I want the whole last line.

So I have a .txt file with the hostnames of all computers I need to examine. 
This .txt file will be read line by line via the variable %list%.

From every logfile I need only the last line copied to an output file.

===
I just tried the solution offered by JosefZ. Unfortunately this does not work for me yet. No lastlines are copied to the resultfile. In the code I removed the extra entry for possible lastlines for there are no empty lines in the logs, I also added an entry for the hostname I want to be available in the result. JosefZ had the filename there:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion    
type nul>output.csv    
set "list=_listing.txt"
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('type "%list%"') do (
  set "host=%%~x" 
  for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('type "%%~x"') do set "lastline=%%G"
  call :lline
)    
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof    
:lline    
  set "filename=.\logs\%filename:&=^&%.txt"
  echo %host%,%lastline%>>output.csv
goto :eof
```

The resultfile shows only the hostnames. I'll puzzle some more with this but all tips are welcome!

===
Got it!!!

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

type nul>output.csv

set "list=_listing.txt"
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('type "%list%"') do (
  set filename=   :: *empty previous filename*
  set lastline=   :: *empty previous lastline* 
  set "host=%%~x" 
  set "filename=.\logs\%host%.txt"  :: *creating the filename from path+hostname+extention*
  for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('type "%filename%"') do set "lastline=%%G"
  call :lline
)

:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:lline

  echo %host%,%lastline%>>output.csv

goto :eof
```

Comment: So - for each filename in a list, you want what information? What is this "4th entry?" Do you want the "4th entry" from each line of the log files plus the entire last line? Are you aware that your "delims" specification means "the delimiters are `.` or `t` or `x` or `,` or `space`" - `delims` is a set of characters, not a string. Show us a sample line by editing it into your question and state which data you want to be extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach with line numbering could fail if a file has more trailing empty lines. Fortunately `for /F` loop ignores (does not iterate) empty lines; let's put to use this feature: in the script used next practices:

- `disabledelayedexpansion` to allow `!` in file names
- `set "list=_listing.txt"` where the `_listing.txt` contains list of file names (full path and extension `.txt` including), one file name on one line: got by `dir /b /s *.txt>_listing.txt`
- `type nul>files\output.csv` to empty the output file (optional)
- `set "lastline=!!!file empty!!!"` to initialize variable `%lastline%`; could be `set "lastline="` as well
- `call :lline` to process variables `%filename%` and `%lastline%`
- `set "filename=%filename:&=^&%"` to allow `&` in file names

The script is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
type nul>files\output.csv

set "list=_listing.txt"
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('type "%list%"') do (
  set "filename=%%~x"
  set "lastline=!!!file empty!!!"

  rem the whole line
  for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('type "%%~x"') do set "lastline=%%G"

  rem the fourth token only
  rem for /F "tokens=4" %%G in ('type "%%~x"') do set "lastline=%%G"

  call :lline
)
:endlocal
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:lline
  set "filename=%filename:&=^&%"
  echo %filename% %lastline%
  rem >>files\output.csv
goto :eof
```

Sample `_listing.txt` file:

```
d:\bat\files\1exclam!ation.txt
d:\bat\files\2exc!lam!ation.txt
d:\bat\files\11per%cent.txt
d:\bat\files\12per%cent%.txt
d:\bat\files\17per%Gcent.txt
d:\bat\files\18per%%Gcent.txt
d:\bat\files\21ampers&nd.txt
d:\bat\files\22ampers&&nd.txt
```

Output:

```
d:\bat>lastlines
d:\bat\files\1exclam!ation.txt 0 15.01.2015  1:52:28.48 -15072 20465
d:\bat\files\2exc!lam!ation.txt 6 15.01.2015  1:52:28.50 3250 16741
d:\bat\files\11per%cent.txt -8 15.01.2015  1:52:28.50 -3692 27910
d:\bat\files\12per%cent%.txt !!!file empty!!!
d:\bat\files\17per%Gcent.txt 0 15.01.2015  1:52:28.56 14508 12374
d:\bat\files\18per%%Gcent.txt 1 15.01.2015  1:52:28.56 30540 26959
d:\bat\files\21ampers&nd.txt 15.01.2015  1:22:50.18
d:\bat\files\22ampers&&nd.txt 15.01.2015  1:22:50.18
```

Honestly, all that ballast is for (possibly) trailing empty lines in files and for (possibly) `!` and `&` in file names only; all could be done with

```
for /f %%x in (%list%) do for /f "skip=%startLine% tokens=4" %%i in (%%x) do echo %%x, %%i >> output.csv
```

Comment: Thanx JosefZ

Reading your script this seems to be what I need. I will try it out and get back with the results ASAP

Comment: Hello JosefZ,

Just tried out your code and it does not work for me yet. Please read the original question for more details.

Comment: @ JosefZ - Your answer was the basic for the sollution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple FOR to iterate a list of values, not FOR /F.

Something like the following should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>>output.csv (
  for %%F in (
    "file1.log"
    "file2.log"
    "file3.log"
    etc.
  ) do (
    for /f %%A in ('find /v /c "" <%%F') do set /a skip=%%A-1
    more +!skip! %%F
  )
)
```

The quotes around the file names are there in case you get a name with spaces.

You could use your LIST variable if it looks something like 

`set LIST="file1.log" "file2.log" "file3.log" etc.`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set LIST="file1.log" "file2.log" "file3.log" etc.    
>>output.csv (
  for %%F in (%LIST%) do (
    for /f %%A in ('find /v /c "" <%%F') do set /a skip=%%A-1
    more +!skip! %%F
  )
)
```

If any of your file names contain the `!` character, then you must toggle delayed expansion ON and OFF within your loop. Otherwise the delayed expansion will corrupt the names when `%%F` is expanded.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set LIST="file1.log" "file2.log" "file3.log" etc.    
>>output.csv (
  for %%F in (%LIST%) do (
    for /f %%A in ('find /v /c "" <%%F') do set /a skip=%%A-1
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    more +!skip! %%F
    endlocal
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks dbenham.
Your solution makes me put all filenames in the batchfile while I have them in a file. This would be extra work but worth a try when there is no other solution.

Comment: @Armand0 - Ah, now I see why you were using FOR /F. If each line simply has one file path on it, then FOR /F will work great with the file. But if each file path is embedded within a larger line, than parsing it out could be complicated. It all depends on the file format.