# loop reading file reads only one kind

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, spring-batch

I know the title is generalized.
Sorry about that.

So my problem is that when I try to read a file, I can only read one kind of them.
What I mean by one kind, is that I can read only the one I create and are typed manually.

When I create a text document and type myself words in it, my loop reads and shows the lines just fine.

But when I try to read a file that has been modified through commands, more precisely with the `>` and `>>` operator, it doesn't do anything. Nothing displays and the script keeps on going. As if it ignores the loop.

Here is the loop I use:

```
for /f "delims==" %%i in (...\TEST.txt) do(
echo %%i
)
```

What's the problem with this? Why doesn't it read my modified files and how can solve this?

I've used these links for information:

[BAT file to read and copy bottom 16 lines from a text file to another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632300/bat-file-to-read-and-copy-bottom-16-lines-from-a-text-file-to-another-one/1632394#1632394)

[CMD.EXE batch script to display last 10 lines from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/cmd-exe-batch-script-to-display-last-10-lines-from-a-txt-file)

Here is the code that is not "working":

```
wmic os get Caption > "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Arch.txt"
wmic OS get OSArchitecture >> "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Arch.txt"

for /f "delims==" %%i in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Arch.txt) do (
echo %%i
)
```

Again, if I set a file that I've manually typed instead of Arch.txt, I will work.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: The problem isn't in the `for` loop or the fact that you're modifying the file using output redirection, it is that `wmic` produces Unicode output.  As shown in the accepted answer on the duplicate, you can work around this using `more`.  In your case, that would look like `wmic ... | more > file.txt`

Comment: Alright. It worked, thank you