# How to get last 450 lines from large txt document via CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files, lines

I'm looking for solution, how to get last 450 lines from large txt document using BATCH files.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/cmd-exe-batch-script-to-display-last-10-lines-from-a-txt-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/cmd-exe-batch-script-to-display-last-10-lines-from-a-txt-file)

Comment: I just posted an improved batch solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/9251975/1012053 as an answer to the question cited in the previous comment. It can efficiently print the last 450 lines without pausing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `tail.exe` from GnuWin32 (package [TextUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)) or UnxUtils.

Then:

```
tail -450 file
```

Comment: Can I write these 450 lines in another txt file?

Comment: @Volodymyr  Prysiazhniuk: Probably you need to read the basics about batch scripts. Use `> file`  to redirect output to a file, for any program, and ` 2> errfile`  to redirect error messages to a 2nd file (`2>&1` to redirect the merge the errors and the standard output).

Answer (score 0):

The hybrid batch file `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) that uses native scripting is robust and quick on large files.

```
findrepl /o:-450 <file.txt >newfile.txt
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.