# How do I display a text file content in CMD?

Tags: cmd

I want to display the content of a text file in a CMD window. In addition, I want to see the new lines that added to file, like `tail -f` command in Unix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a windows equivalent of the unix tail command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)

Answer (score 540):

You can use the `more` command. For example:

```
more filename.txt
```

Take a look at *[GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)* or [download it](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUpdates.zip):

Comment: How is this similar to tail -f? tail -f loops forever. How did you replicate the -f of it?

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. Not sure why its rated so high. OP was looking for 2 things - a windows alternative to cat, and an alternative to tail -f. If you're going to install the GNU utilities for windows, you can then use those things.

Answer (score 300):

We can use the 'type' command to see file contents in cmd.

Example -

```
type abc.txt
```

More information can be found [HERE](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html).

Comment: I like this answer because it's not interactive.  `more` shows N screens at a time that you have to click through

Answer (score 29):

I don't think there is a built-in function for that

```
xxxx.txt > con
```

This opens the files in the default text editor in windows...

```
type xxxx.txt
```

This displays the file in the current window. Maybe this has params you can use...

There is a similar question here: [CMD.EXE batch script to display last 10 lines from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/cmd-exe-batch-script-to-display-last-10-lines-from-a-txt-file)
So there is a "more" command to display a file from the given line, or you can use the GNU Utilities for Win32 what bryanph suggested in his link.

Comment: Hey may you tell me where the command
> con is documented, I searched for it but couldn't find any :)
anyways it is working fine ;)

Answer (score 29):

To show content of a file:

`type file.txt` - cmd

`cat file.txt` - bash/powershell

Answer (score 14):

You can use the ['more'](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html) command to see the content of the file:

```
more filename.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for trying to help. Please explain how the windows version of more can be used to automatically see newly arriving lines in a text file. That would make your answer more directly relate to OPs question, i.e. demonstrate the "tail -f"-compatibility OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

Using a single PowerShell command to retrieve the file ending:

```
powershell -nologo "& "Get-Content -Wait c:\logFile.log -Tail 10"
```

It applies to PowerShell 3.0 and newer.

Another option is to create a file called TAIL.CMD with this code:

```
powershell -nologo "& "Get-Content -Wait %1 -Tail %2"
```

Comment: It works, but it's too slow, as PowerShell may take 2 or 3 seconds to start.

Answer (score 4):

To do this, you can use Microsoft's more advanced command-line shell called "[Windows PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)." It should come standard on the latest versions of Windows, but you can [download it from Microsoft](http://microsoft.com/powershell) if you don't already have it installed.

To get the last five lines in the text file simply read the file using `Get-Content`, then have `Select-Object` pick out the last five items/lines for you:

```
Get-Content c:\scripts\test.txt | Select-Object -last 5
```

Source: [Using the Get-Content Cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843.aspx)

Comment: @Eyal 's answer is more fitting being called from the cmd, and the code is better using Tail than piping into Select-Object. You can't do -Wait while doing Select Object as well. This is not what the OP is requesting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in some methods:

One is the `type` command: `type filename`
Another is the `more` command: `more filename`
With `more` you can also do that: `type filename | more`

The last option is using a `for`
`for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (filename) do (echo.%%A)`
This will go for each line and display it's content. This is an equivalent of the `type` command, but it's another method of reading the content.

If you are asking what to use, use the `more` command as it will make a pause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to display the content of the file live, and update when the file is altered, just use this script:

```
@echo off
:start
cls
type myfile.txt
goto start
```

That will repeat forever until you close the cmd window.

Comment: This does not replicate the functionality of tail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either more filename.[extension] or type filename.[extension]

[image]

Comment: try to give a more detailed explanation, and please update your image to load directly in StackOverflow

Comment: both commands were suggested several times before (and don't even answer the question). So this answer adds nothing but noise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in option available with Windows. To constantly monitor logs you can use this free application [BareTailPro](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the TAIL utility from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657).

Here are additional details -- [Tail command for Windows (CMD)](http://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/).

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display for example all `.config` (or `.ini`) file name and file content into one doc for user reference (and by this I mean user not knowing shell command i.e. 95% of them), you can try this :

```
FORFILES /M *myFile.ini /C "cmd /c echo File name : @file >> %temp%\stdout.txt && type @path >> %temp%\stdout.txt && echo. >> %temp%\stdout.txt" | type %temp%\stdout.txt
```

Explanation :

- ForFiles : loop on a directory (and child, etc) each file meeting criteria

  - able to return the current file name being process (@file)
  - able to return the full path file being process (@path)
- Type : Output the file content

Ps : The last pipe command is pointing the `%temp%` file and output the aggregate content.  If you wish to copy/paste in some documentation, just open the stdout.txt file in textpad.

Answer (score -2):

```
tail -3 d:\text_file.txt

tail -1 d:\text_file.txt
```

I assume this was added to Windows cmd.exe at some point.

Comment: no, `tail` is still not a standard windows command. Usually it's part of an addon like cygwin, GNU or others.

Comment: This is not a good answer, you are just saying that this has been implemented into Windows, but no, please check your information before answering.