# Getting text from .bat file in CMD

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have created a OpenNotepad.bat file with text stating `"C:\windows\system32" notepad.exe` and saved it to my desktop. I have created a Java class. What do I have to type in the cmd to get that text from the .bat file?

Is there a specific command that I should use to get the command prompt to display that text?

Here is my Java code:

```
public class OpenBatchFile {
    public OpenBatchFile() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Get Runtime object
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec("cmd /c start Desktop:\\OpenNotePad.bat");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am totally new to this. I referred to this tutorial:
*[Execute batch file from Java Code using Runtime class](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2016/05/execute-batch-file-from-java-code-using.html)*

Comment: If you have to read the content from batch file why are you executing the file, instead of reading the content ?

Comment: I am totally new to this and i followed a tutorial: http://www.awasthiashish.com/2016/05/execute-batch-file-from-java-code-using.html

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking... are you looking for `dos` command that will display files contents (`type [filename]`) - or you want to read the contents from `java`?

Comment: I want the cmd to display the content of what is inside the OpenNotePad.bat

Comment: then you should use something like `type OpenNotePad.bat`

Comment: Is there any specific commands that i should use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display text file content in cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217476/how-to-display-text-file-content-in-cmd)

Comment: Ok the `type OpenNotePad.bat` command worked. And the command `more OpenNotePad.bat` can be used too ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Susmitha Why do you have duplicate accounts and use the one to upvote questions on the other? Each of your account questions all have upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

When in `cmd.exe` console, type the command `help` which will display all possible commands you can run in a cmd prompt or batch... If you read through each, you will notice two that stand out:

```
MORE           Displays output one screen at a time.
TYPE           Displays the contents of a text file.
```

This will display the content of any file if you use them like:

```
type filename.txt
more filename.txt
```

or

```
type "c:\program files\some dir\filename.txt"
more "c:\program files\some dir\filename.txt"
```