# Get catalina.out in Apache tomcat log

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, tail

Currently trying to open the file gives this error:

```
C:\Users\....\....\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\logs>catalina.out
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

What I have done is to have application running in the webapps and start `tomcat` by using following command:

```
catalina.bat jpda start
```

And now I want to see the logs in windows. In Ubuntu, `tail -f catalina.out` can be used. But how to see tomcat logs in windows forcefully?

Comment: What application are you using to open the log file? Use an application that opens the file for reading only.

Comment: Im using cmd... application like?

Comment: Instead of `tail -f catalina.out` try `type catalina.out`

Comment: I just gave an example im using windows obviously

Comment: `cmd` is not an application that reads files.

Comment: Is there anyway i can open the file from cmd or if not what is the application i should use

Answer (score 0):

As stated in answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217476/how-do-i-display-a-text-file-content-in-cmd), you can try `more catalina.out` or `type catalina.out`