# Using Windows Command Prompt to read last 10 lines of a text file

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

Can anyone please advise how to use Windows Command Prompt to read last 10 lines of a text file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMD.EXE batch script to display last 10 lines from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523181/cmd-exe-batch-script-to-display-last-10-lines-from-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 1):

I use this:  **Get-Content $args[0] -Tail $args[1] -Wait**

Usage: **tail.ps1 [fileName] [lastNumberOfLines]**

It is designed for log files to scroll as they are being written.  You can remove the -Wait if you just want to see the last lines of a file that isn't changing.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use PowerShell.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content .\rrreg.ps1 | Select-Object -Last 3"
```

Iterating across each line can also be done.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-Content .\rrreg.ps1 | Select-Object -Last 3"`) DO (
    ECHO %%s
)
```

Of course, having a `tail` command on your system would make `tail -10 thefile.txt` possible. How much easier can it be than that?

Comment: someone voted this down, but it's actually a good answer. I've tried it on a 4Gb file. Took a while to get to the last 3 lines, but did it

Comment: adding to my previous comment, I tried it on a 4Gb file, but ran the command from a powershell window, so only ran the part "Get-Content .\YourFileHere | Select-Object -Last 3", without the quotes obviously