# Windows command line tool analagous to UN*X "tail" command?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, dos, error-log

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a windows equivalent of the unix tail command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)

The tail command on the DOS does not seem to be recognized on my XP. Any suggestions on printing last few lines on a very big log file on DOS.

Thanks
Arun

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)