# Unix tail equivalent command in Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, tail

I have to look at the last few lines of a large file (typical size is 500MB-2GB). I am looking for a equivalent of Unix command `tail` for Windows Powershell. A few alternatives available on are,

http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/

and

```
Get-Content [filename] | Select-Object -Last 10
```

For me, it is not allowed to use the first alternative, and the second alternative is slow. Does anyone know of an efficient implementation of tail for PowerShell.

Comment: How can we know if you will be allowed to use what we suggest if you don't say why you're not allowed to use the first alternative?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the `tail` command provided in http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/UnxUtils.zip/download?

Comment: this is in a production machine where I was not allowed allowed to copy copy any external executables. Some weird policies. :) Can't help it. Thanks for the Unxutils link.

Comment: [https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/unix-to-powershell-tail](https://devcentral.f5.com/blogs/us/unix-to-powershell-tail) demonstrates pure PoSH implementation of this.

Comment: No need to use Select-Object: `Get-Content [filename] -last 10` and add `-tail`for -f

Answer (score 641, accepted):

Use the `-wait` parameter with Get-Content, which displays lines as they are added to the file. This feature was present in PowerShell v1, but for some reason not documented well in v2.

Here is an example

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\scripts\test.txt" -Wait
```

Once you run this, update and save the file and you will see the changes on the console.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that all arguments that exist also appear in help, yet `man gc -par wait` tells me there is no parameter. But I think this doesn't solve the problem that the OP has, since they asked for `tail`, not `tail -f` and an efficient implementation as well. Since this one also reads the complete file before returning the last lines this is painful for the file sizes they expect.

Comment: Gotcha. May be IO.File has some way to seek to the required position. I will have to experiment a bit

Comment: I guess one could implement it as a PowerShell function, using the normal .NET APIs. Seeking to the end, search backwards until the desired number of lines is found and emit them. Not pretty, probably, but might work. I just can't wrap my head around it right now, otherwise I would have started writing already ;-)

Comment: FYI, this is what the Get-FileTail (alias tail) implementation does in PSCX.  If you're curious you can look at the source code: http://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/78514#1358075

Comment: The solution "Get-Content -Path "C:\scripts\test.txt" -Wait" doesn't work well for large files as Joey commented. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: @Joey -Wait is a dynamic parameter that only applies to the FileSystem provider.  GC can be used on any provider that implements that API.  The only way besides documentation that I know to discover these is to use (gcm Get-Content).Parameters from within the appropriate provider path.  Don't use the alias "gc" because the dynamic parameters will not show up.

Comment: @Jason: Ah, damn it, I should have known. Yes, makes sense.

Comment: I know it was a while ago, but this requires the process writing to the file to open, append, close it before Get-Content will work. If the writing process never closes the file then it won't work which is not the case with tail -f.

Comment: Oddly, -Wait only shows me new lines when I access a log file in some way (such as selecting it in Windows Explorer). Tail provides updates as new lines are written to my file. With -Wait, I can leave a PowerShell window open happily showing no new lines while the file is being written to. If I then pop over and click on the file in Windows Explorer, suddenly PowerShell "wakes up" and catches up the remaining lines. Is this a bug?

Comment: @JoshL - I noticed the same thing with [Epilog](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/EpilogWindows/index.html), I guess it's using PowerShells under the bonnet.

Comment: @JoshL: Indeed this does not work like `tail -f`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919180/get-content-wait-not-working-as-described-in-the-documentation

Comment: Yeah, this is really not the same. Not only does it not handle persistently opened files as mentioned - it also has to print the entire file before it'll start showing you the changes - which is rather hopeless if you're trying to `tail` a log file 100s of MB in size.

Comment: @JoshL - View the folder in details mode in Explorer - when you click the file, watch the file size. It seems explorer doesn't really 'care' about refreshing the file until you click on it. Interesting that this is happening to PS as well, it must be lower-level than both Explorer and PS.

Comment: Per the comment of JoshL above, I think this behavior is due to the application caching it's log writes and not flushing them to disk until the file is read.  This is a common strategy for making logging more efficient.  It certainly makes it a pain, though.  You could perhaps work around it by having another script read (part?) of the file periodically...

Comment: Great stuff - been trying to find a way to do this for ages. If I'm ever in Bangalore, I'll buy you a beer! :-D

Comment: Sorry for silly question, but how do you exit the reading? How to tell the wait to stop waiting?

Comment: CTRL+C should stop wait on the content.

Comment: Powershell has an alias for cat, by default. So `cat "C:\scripts\test.txt" -Wait` would work as well, if you're accustom to the Unix syntax. You can also alter your powershell profile so you can just use the tail command: `function tail { cat $args -Wait }` will let you do `tail "C:\scripts\test.txt"`.  You can find the path to your profile in the $PROFILE variable.

Comment: Can I tail a command, not a file? Such as history -tail 10?

Answer (score 308):

For completeness I'll mention that Powershell 3.0 now has a -Tail flag on Get-Content

```
Get-Content ./log.log -Tail 10
```

gets the last 10 lines of the file

```
Get-Content ./log.log -Wait -Tail 10
```

gets the last 10 lines of the file and waits for more

Also, for those *nix users, note that most systems alias **cat** to Get-Content, so this usually works

```
cat ./log.log -Tail 10
```

Comment: @LauraLiparulo in what way does this not work? I've used it before definitely.

Comment: I just used it and it worked spot on in this format `Get-Content .\test.txt -Wait -Tail 1`

Comment: @LauraLiparulo - Works for me also: `Get-Content -Path .\sync.log -Wait -Tail 10`

Comment: On ISE, I used to use while($true)/sleep and switched to this one, but this one also locks entire ISE and cannot run scripts on other tabs. Should I just start a new ISE instance?

Comment: @Teomanshipahi In whwat way did the `-Wait` parameter not work for you?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer conceptually I misunderstood how ISE works. I thought different tabs have their own context, but if one script runs on one tab, I cannot run other scripts on other tabs. I think this is expected behaviour.

Comment: `cat -tail` makes sense to me.

Answer (score 123):

As of PowerShell version 3.0, the Get-Content cmdlet has a **-Tail** parameter that should help. See [the technet library online help for Get-Content.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh849787.aspx)

Comment: Link to download here – http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595.

Comment: Note for some - PS 3.0 is Unavailable to Windows XP and Vista.

Comment: I use the technique mentioned by Dan but I record it in my $PROFILE. Open it with notepad $PROFILE. Then in the text document, create a new function:
function Tail ($path)
{
      Get-content -tail 15 -path $path -wait
}
This way you can access the function each time you start PowerShell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. -Wait flag mentioned in currently accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 31):

I used some of the answers given here but just a heads up that

```
Get-Content -Path Yourfile.log -Tail 30 -Wait
```

will chew up memory after awhile. A colleague left such a "tail" up over the last day and it went up to 800 MB.  I don't know if Unix tail behaves the same way (but I doubt it).  So it's fine to use for short term applications, but be careful with it.

Answer (score 20):

Probably too late for an answere but, try this one

```
Get-Content <filename> -tail <number of items wanted> -wait
```

Comment: None of these have a follow options.  Which is the 99% use case for using the `tail` command.

Comment: @Andries did you see Ravikanth's answer? You can use `-Wait` to follow.

Comment: Added the flag suggested by @JasonS

Answer (score 19):

[PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) provides the [`Get-FileTail` cmdlet](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx/blob/master/Src/Pscx/Commands/IO/GetFileTailCommand.cs). It looks like a suitable solution for the task. Note: I did not try it with extremely large files but the description says it efficiently tails the contents and it is designed for large log files.

```
NAME
    Get-FileTail

SYNOPSIS
    PSCX Cmdlet: Tails the contents of a file - optionally waiting on new content.

SYNTAX
    Get-FileTail [-Path] <String[]> [-Count <Int32>] [-Encoding <EncodingParameter>] [-LineTerminator <String>] [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]

    Get-FileTail [-LiteralPath] <String[]> [-Count <Int32>] [-Encoding <EncodingParameter>] [-LineTerminator <String>] [-Wait] [<CommonParameters>]

DESCRIPTION
    This implentation efficiently tails the cotents of a file by reading lines from the end rather then processing the entire file. This behavior is crucial for ef
    ficiently tailing large log files and large log files over a network.  You can also specify the Wait parameter to have the cmdlet wait and display new content
    as it is written to the file.  Use Ctrl+C to break out of the wait loop.  Note that if an encoding is not specified, the cmdlet will attempt to auto-detect the
     encoding by reading the first character from the file. If no character haven't been written to the file yet, the cmdlet will default to using Unicode encoding
    . You can override this behavior by explicitly specifying the encoding via the Encoding parameter.
```

Comment: There's a bug in the current version that is fixed in daily bits.  I would recommend grabbing the latest bits and compiling them at least until we get an updated version released.

Comment: The version 2.0 takes ages to show the 10 last lines of a 1GB csv file, and differently from `Get-Content [filename] | Select-Object -Last 10` it can't be aborted

Answer (score 15):

Just some additions to previous answers. There are aliases defined for Get-Content, for example if you are used to UNIX you might like `cat`, and there are also `type` and `gc`. So instead of

```
Get-Content -Path <Path> -Wait -Tail 10
```

you can write

```
# Print whole file and wait for appended lines and print them
cat <Path> -Wait
# Print last 10 lines and wait for appended lines and print them
cat <Path> -Tail 10 -Wait
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a useful tip on this subject concerning multiple files.

Following a single log file (like 'tail -f' in Linux) with PowerShell 5.2 (Win7 and Win10) is easy (just use "Get-Content MyFile -Tail 1 -Wait").  However, watching **MULTIPLE** log files at once seems complicated.  With PowerShell 7.x+ however, I've found an easy way by using "Foreach-Object -Parrallel".  This performs multiple 'Get-Content' commands concurrently.  For example:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\logs\*.log | Foreach-Object -Parallel { Get-Content $_ -Tail 1 -Wait }
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Powershell V2 and below, get-content reads the entire file, so it was of no use to me.  The following code works for what I needed, though there are likely some issues with character encodings.  This is effectively tail -f, but it could be easily modified to get the last x bytes, or last x lines if you want to search backwards for line breaks.

```
$filename = "\wherever\your\file\is.txt"
$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.FileStream($filename, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite))
#start at the end of the file
$lastMaxOffset = $reader.BaseStream.Length

while ($true)
{
    Start-Sleep -m 100

    #if the file size has not changed, idle
    if ($reader.BaseStream.Length -eq $lastMaxOffset) {
        continue;
    }

    #seek to the last max offset
    $reader.BaseStream.Seek($lastMaxOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) | out-null

    #read out of the file until the EOF
    $line = ""
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
        write-output $line
    }

    #update the last max offset
    $lastMaxOffset = $reader.BaseStream.Position
}
```

I found most of the code to do this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7568/Tail-NET).

Comment: Is it true that Get-Content with the -Tail option reads the entire file? On large files it seems OK for me.

Comment: I believe it depends on the PS version.  I've updated the answer.  I was stuck on a server without the ability to install anything at the time, so the above code was useful.

Answer (score 4):

I took @hajamie's solution and wrapped it up into a slightly more convenient script wrapper.

I added an option to start from an offset before the end of the file, so you can use the tail-like functionality of reading a certain amount from the end of the file. Note the offset is in bytes, not lines.

There's also an option to continue waiting for more content.

Examples (assuming you save this as TailFile.ps1):

```
.\TailFile.ps1 -File .\path\to\myfile.log -InitialOffset 1000000
.\TailFile.ps1 -File .\path\to\myfile.log -InitialOffset 1000000 -Follow:$true
.\TailFile.ps1 -File .\path\to\myfile.log -Follow:$true
```

And here is the script itself...

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter the path to a file to tail")][string]$File = "",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Enter the number of bytes from the end of the file")][int]$InitialOffset = 10248,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,HelpMessage="Continuing monitoring the file for new additions?")][boolean]$Follow = $false
)

$ci = get-childitem $File
$fullName = $ci.FullName

$reader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.FileStream($fullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite))
#start at the end of the file
$lastMaxOffset = $reader.BaseStream.Length - $InitialOffset

while ($true)
{
    #if the file size has not changed, idle
    if ($reader.BaseStream.Length -ge $lastMaxOffset) {
        #seek to the last max offset
        $reader.BaseStream.Seek($lastMaxOffset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) | out-null

        #read out of the file until the EOF
        $line = ""
        while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
            write-output $line
        }

        #update the last max offset
        $lastMaxOffset = $reader.BaseStream.Position
    }

    if($Follow){
        Start-Sleep -m 100
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There have been many valid answers, however, none of them has the *same* syntax as [tail in linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html). The following function can be stored in your `$Home\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` for persistency (see [powershell profiles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6#the-profile-files) for more details).

This allows you to call...

```
tail server.log
tail -n 5 server.log
tail -f server.log
tail -Follow -Lines 5 -Path server.log
```

which comes quite close to the linux syntax.

```
function tail {
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Get the last n lines of a text file.
    .PARAMETER Follow
        output appended data as the file grows
    .PARAMETER Lines
        output the last N lines (default: 10)
    .PARAMETER Path
        path to the text file
    .INPUTS
        System.Int
        IO.FileInfo
    .OUTPUTS
        System.String
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> tail c:\server.log
    .EXAMPLE
        PS> tail -f -n 20 c:\server.log
#>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType('System.String')]
    Param(
        [Alias("f")]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$Follow,

        [Alias("n")]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Int]$Lines = 10,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=5)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [IO.FileInfo]$Path
    )
    if ($Follow)
    {
        Get-Content -Path $Path -Tail $Lines -Wait
    }
    else
    {
        Get-Content -Path $Path -Tail $Lines
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try `Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools`

it contains a `tail.exe` which can be run on Windows system.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657

Answer (score 1):

For those admins who live by the axiom that less typing is best, here is the shortest version I can find:

```
gc filename -wai -ta 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic, but does what you need without any addon modules or PS version requirements:

`while ($true) {Clear-Host; gc E:\test.txt | select -last 3; sleep 2 }`

Comment: That's brutal on large files.

Comment: My workaround was: `while($true) { Clear-Host; Get-Content <filename> -tail 40; sleep 1 }` :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to download all of the UNIX commands compiled for Windows from this GitHub repository: https://github.com/George-Ogden/UNIX

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Before you answer a question take notice of the 12 other answers, 3 having scores over 100.