# Get-Content -wait not working as described in the documentation

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've noticed that when `Get-Content path/to/logfile -Wait`, the output is actually not refreshed every second as the documentation explains it should. If I go in Windows Explorer to the folder where the log file is and Refresh the folder, then `Get-Content` would output the latest changes to the log file.

If I try `tail -f` with cygwin on the same log file (not at the same time than when trying `get-content`), then it tails as one would expect, refreshing real time without me having to do anything.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: I found a Powershell bug report on Connect that matches this issue (https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/792983/get-content-wait-does-not-follow-a-file). Everyone, should go and vote for a resolution to this annoying issue.

Comment: Finally, this works now in Powershell 5.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit:** *Bernhard König reports in the comments that this has finally been fixed in Powershell 5.*

You are quite right. The `-Wait` option on `Get-Content` waits until the file has been closed before it reads more content. It is possible to demonstrate this in Powershell, but can be tricky to get right as loops such as:

```
while (1){
get-date | add-content c:\tesetfiles\test1.txt 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

will open and close the output file every time round the loop.

To demonstrate the issue open two Powershell windows (or two tabs in the ISE). In one enter this command:

```
PS C:\> 1..30 | % { "${_}: Write $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")"; start-sleep 1 } >C:\temp\t.txt
```

That will run for 30 seconds writing 1 line into the file each second, but it doesn't close and open the file each time.

In the other window use `Get-Content` to read the file:

```
get-content c:\temp\t.txt -tail 1 -wait | % { "$_ read at $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")" }
```

With the `-Wait` option you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the command so running that command 3 times waiting a few seconds after each of the first two and a longer wait after the third gave me this output:

```
PS C:\> get-content c:\temp\t.txt -tail 1 -wait | % { "$_ read at $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")" }
8: Write 12:15:09 read at 12:15:09

PS C:\> get-content c:\temp\t.txt -tail 1 -wait | % { "$_ read at $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")" }
13: Write 12:15:14 read at 12:15:15

PS C:\> get-content c:\temp\t.txt -tail 1 -wait | % { "$_ read at $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")" }
19: Write 12:15:20 read at 12:15:20
20: Write 12:15:21 read at 12:15:32
21: Write 12:15:22 read at 12:15:32
22: Write 12:15:23 read at 12:15:32
23: Write 12:15:24 read at 12:15:32
24: Write 12:15:25 read at 12:15:32
25: Write 12:15:26 read at 12:15:32
26: Write 12:15:27 read at 12:15:32
27: Write 12:15:28 read at 12:15:32
28: Write 12:15:29 read at 12:15:32
29: Write 12:15:30 read at 12:15:32
30: Write 12:15:31 read at 12:15:32
```

From this I can clearly see:

1. Each time the command is run it gets the latest line written to the file. i.e. There is no problem with caching and no buffers needing flushed.
2. Only a single line is read and then no further output appears until the command running in the other window completes.
3. Once it does complete all of the pending lines appear together. This must have been triggered by the source program closing the file.

Also when I repeated the exercise with the `Get-Content` command running in two other windows one window read line 3 then just waited, the other window read line 6, so the line is definitely being written to the file.

It seems pretty conclusive that the `-Wait` option is waiting for a file close event, not waiting for the advertised 1 second. The documentation is wrong.

**Edit:**
I should add, as Adi Inbar seems to insistent that I'm wrong, that the examples I gave here use Powershell only as that seemed most appropriate for a Powershell discussion. I did also verify using Python that the behaviour is exactly as I described:

Content written to a file is readable by a new `Get-Content -Wait` command immediately provided the application has flushed its buffer.

A Powershell instance using `Get-Content -Wait` will not display new content in the file that is being written even though another Powershell instance, started later, sees the later data. This proves conclusively that the data is accessible to Powershell and `Get-Content -Wait` is not polling at 1 second intervals but waiting for some trigger event before it next looks for data.

The size of the file as reported by `dir` is updating while lines are being added, so it is not a case of Powershell waiting for the directory entry size to be updated.

When the process writing the file closes it, the `Get-Content -Wait` displays the new content almost instantly. If it were waiting until the data was flushed to disk there would be up to a delay until Windows flushed it's disk cache.

@AdiInbar, I'm afraid you don't understand what Excel does when you save a file. Have a closer look. If you are editing `test.xlsx` then there is also a hidden file `~test.xlsx` in the same folder. Use `dir ~test.xlsx -hidden | select CreationTime` to see when it was created. Save your file and now `test.xlsx` will have the creation time from `~test.xlsx`. In other words saving in Excel saves to the `~` file then deletes the original, renames the `~` file to the original name and creates a new `~` file. There's a lot of opening and closing going on there.

Before you save it has the file you are looking at open, and after that file is open, but its a different file. I think Excel is too complex a scenario to say exactly what triggers `Get-Content` to show new content but I'm sure you mis-interpreted it.

Comment: A few counterpoints to elaborate on my response to your comment. First, a clarification. It sounds like you misunderstood what I was saying about buffering, because the tests with starting and stopping `Get-Content -Wait` miss the point. I didn't say that the console output from `Get-Content -Wait` was being buffered, I was talking about write buffering of the pipeline output to the text file. Since new lines are displayed only when the content of the file changes *on the disk*, they're not displayed by `Get-Content -Wait` as long as the writes to the text file are being buffered.

Comment: Second, you need to look at a broader data set. You're *inferring* that the reason the remaining lines appear when the pipeline completes is that the file was closed, but the evidence is by no means conclusive, and in fact the inference is incorrect. `Get-Content -Wait` displays the additional data as soon as it's *written to the disk*, not just when the file is closed. To prove this, execute `Get-Content -Wait` on an Excel document. When you add data to the spreadsheet, as soon as you save from Excel you'll see `Get-Content -Wait` spit out more data.

Comment: ...Excel does not close the file when you save, only when you close the file's window or exit the program (as you can prove by attempting to delete it at the prompt while it's still open in Excel).

Comment: Third, your hypothesis directly contradicts the behavior that the OP noted in his question, which I've confirmed through my own testing: Refreshing the folder in Windows Explorer causes `Get-Content -Wait` to output the content that has been added to the text file since the previous time that it produced output. I've verified that this observation by the OP applies to the test you described. Refreshing the folder doesn't close the file, but it does flush the write cache if any of the contents of the folder have changed.

Comment: @AdiInbar, I updated my answer to address most of your points. I'll look at your last point about Explorer later: it must be doing something (e.g. opening and closing the file) that triggers `Get-Content` to look at the new content that is already in the file, but it isn't cache-flushing that does this as I've tried flushing caches.

Comment: +1 fwiw - Using procmon, it shows clearly that powershell only kicks in after an IRP_MJ_CLOSE event while tail (cygwin) is constantly polling the file. Powershell seems to be way more resource friendly but by sacrificing realtime updates to a file like tail does. *(io, -Wait is next to useless)*

Comment: This isn't correct. As @AdiInbar points out, it doesn't explain the Explorer refresh behaviour. Also, if I run `Get-Content -Wait` in one window monitoring a log that's logging every few seconds, it doesn't update, but if I fire up a second powershell window and run the same command, it triggers the first window to catch up once. Note nothing should be closing the file in this case. I'm not sure I buy the OS write cache explanation either mind you, but I'll comment on that answer separately.

Comment: Pretty sure it's that Powershell is checking the file's `Last Modified` property. Closing the file updates this, hence your observations, but so does anything that explicitly queries the file's properties. I posted more details as an answer.

Comment: @CupawnTae that sounds plausible.

Comment: I did some experimenting - writing to `LastWriteTime` (even if you write back the current value) makes `Get-Content` "wake up". Still not 100% conclusive because the act of updating the file could be doing an open/close for example, so I tried writing `LastAccessTime`. This does update the property on the file, but it *doesn't* wake up the `Get-Content`, so it's looking very likely that `LastWriteTime` / `Last Modified` is the culprit

Comment: After upgrading to Powershell 5, this does now finally work as expected.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like Powershell is monitoring the file's `Last Modified` property. The problem is that "for performance reasons" the NTFS metadata containing this property is [not automatically updated](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it.aspx)  except under certain circumstances.

One cirumstance is when the file handle is closed (hence [@Duncan's observations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22014265/1469259)). Another is when the file's information is queried directly, hence the Explorer refresh behaviour mentioned in the question.

You can observe the correlation by having Powershell monitoring a log with `Get-Content -Wait` and having Explorer open in the folder in details view with `Last Modified` column visible. Notice that `Last Modified` doesn't update automatically as the file is modified.

Now get the properties of the file in another window. E.g. at a command prompt, `type` the file. Or open another Explorer window in the same folder, and right-click the file and get its properties (for me, just right-clicking is enough). As soon as you do that, the first Explorer window will automatically update the `Last Modified` column and Powershell will notice the update and catch up with the log. In Powershell, touching the `LastWriteTime` property is enough:

```
(Get-Item file.log).LastWriteTime = (Get-Item file.log).LastWriteTime
```

or

```
(Get-Item file.log).LastWriteTime = Get-Date
```

So this is now working for me:

```
Start-Job {
  $f=Get-Item full\path\to\log
  while (1) {
    $f.LastWriteTime = Get-Date
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
  }
}
Get-Content path\to\log -Wait
```

Comment: This is thee answer or at least the description to the problem. Here is a lengthy thread on the matter (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e8ed4036-d822-43d3-9ee5-dd03df3d9bfc/why-doesnt-wait-work-and-why-doesnt-anyone-seem-to-care?forum=winserverpowershell).

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell us how to reproduce that?

I can start this script on one PS session:

```
get-content c:\testfiles\test1.txt -wait
```

and this in another session:

```
while (1){
get-date | add-content c:\tesetfiles\test1.txt 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

And I see the new entries being written in the first session.

Comment: I tried your tests scenario and does work. My particular case is with a .Net app writing text to a log file via log4net. That's the file that "-wait" won't work on. My devenv is Windows 2008. I initially thought it was the way log4net flushes the content to the file, but if that was the case, why is that tail -f, via cygwin, manages to do proper tailing on the log file...

Comment: I don't know.  The test is doing a sequence of write operations, opening and closing the file each time.  If log4net does streaming writes, that would be one difference in the scenarios.

Comment: @mjolinor, with all due respect to a 10K rep user and an established powershell expert: do you think this is an answer, or does it fit better as a comment?

Comment: I actually started out making it a comment, but thought I should post the code I used to test.

Comment: @julio.g I get the same results "-wait"ing on a log4net log file in windows 10. I think there's something a bit special about how log4net is writing the file.

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that `Get-Content -Wait` does refresh every second, and shows you changes when the file changes on the disk. I'm not sure what `tail -f` is doing differently, but based on your description I'm just about certain that this issue is not with PowerShell but with write caching. I can't rule out the possibility that log4net is doing the caching, but I strongly suspect that OS-level caching is the culprit, for two reasons:

1. The documentation for log4j/log4net says that it flushes the buffer after every append operation by default, and I presume that if you had explicitly configured it not to flush after every append, you'd be aware of that.
2. I know for a fact that refreshing Windows Explorer triggers a write buffer flush if any files in the directory have changed. That's because it actually reads the file contents, not just the metadata, in order to provide extended information such as thumbnails and previews, and the read operation causes the write buffer to flush. So, if you're seeing the delayed updates every time you refresh the logfile's directory in Windows Explorer, that points strongly in this direction.

Try this: Open Device Manager, expand the **Disk Drives** node, open the Properties of the disk on which the logfile is stored, switch to the **Policies** tab, and uncheck **Enable write caching on the device**. I think you'll find that `Get-Content -Wait` will now show you the changes as they happen.

As for why `tail -f` is showing you the changes immediately as it is, I can only speculate. Maybe you're using it to monitor a logfile on a different drive, or perhaps Cygwin requests frequent flushes while you're running `tail -f`, to address this very issue.

---

**UPDATE:**

Duncan commented below that it is an issue with PowerShell, and posted an answer contending that `Get-Content -Wait` doesn't output new results until the file is closed, contrary to the documentation.

However, based on information already established and further testing, I've confirmed conclusively that it does *not* wait for the file to be closed, but outputs new data added to the file as soon as it's written to disk, and that the issue the OP is seeing is almost definitely due to write buffering.

To prove this, let the facts be submitted to a candid world:

- I created an Excel spreadsheet, and ran `Get-Content -Wait` against the .xlsx file. When I entered new data into the spreadsheet, the `Get-Content -Wait` did not produce new output, which is expected while the new information is only in RAM and not on disk. However, whenever I saved the spreadsheet after adding data, new output was produced immediately.

Excel does *not* close the file when you save it. The file remains open until you close the Window from Excel, or exit Excel. You can verify this by trying to delete, rename, or otherwise modify the .xlsx file after you've saved it, while the window is still open in Excel.

The OP stated that he gets new output when he refreshes the folder in Windows Explorer. Refreshing the folder listing does not close the file. It *does* flush the write buffer if any of the files have changed. That's because it has to read the file's attributes, and this operation flushes the write buffer. I'll try to find some references for this, but as I noted above, I know for a fact that this is true.

I verified this behavior by running the following modified version of Duncan's test, which runs for 1,000 iterations instead of 50, and displays progress at the console so that you can track exactly how the output in your `Get-Content -Wait` window relates to the data that the pipeline has added to the file:

```powershell
1..1000 | %{"${_}: Write $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")"; Write-Host -NoNewline "$_..."; Start-Sleep 1} > .\gcwtest.txt
```

While this was running, I ran `Get-Content -Wait .\gcwtest.txt` in another window, and opened the directory in Windows Explorer. I found that if I refresh, more output is produced any time the file size in KB changes, and *sometimes* but not always even if nothing visible has changed. (More on the implications of that inconsistency later...)

Using the same test, I opened a third PowerShell window, and observed that all of the following trigger an immediate update in the `Get-Content -Wait` listing:

- Listing the file's contents with plain old `Get-Content .\gcwtest.txt`
- Reading any of the file's attributes. However, for attributes that don't change, only the first read triggers an update.

For example, `(gi .\gcwtest.txt).lastwritetime` triggers more output multiple times. On the other hand, `(gi .\gcwtest.txt).mode` or `(gi .\gcwtest.txt).directory` trigger more output the first time each, but not if you repeat them. Also note the following:

**»**   This behavior is not 100% consistent. Sometimes, reading **Mode** or **Directory** doesn't trigger more output the first time, but it does if you repeat the operation. All subsequent repetitions after the first one that triggers updated output have no effect.

**»**   If you repeat the test, reading attributes that are the same does not trigger output, *unless* you delete the .txt file before running the pipeline again. In fact, sometimes even `(gi .\gcwtest.txt).lastwritetime` doesn't trigger more output if you repeat the test without deleting **gcwtest.txt**.

**»**   If you issue `(gi .\gcwtest.txt).lastwritetime` multiple times in one second, only the first one triggers output, i.e. only when the result has changed.

Opening the file in a text editor. If you use an editor that keeps the file handle open (notepad does not), you'll see that closing the file without saving does not cause `Get-Content -Wait` to output the lines added by the pipeline since you opened the file in the editor.

Tab-completing the file's name

- After you try any of the tests above a few times, you many find that `Get-Content -Wait` outputs more lines periodically for the remainder of the pipeline's execution, even if you don't do anything. Not one line at a time, but in batches.
- The inconsistency in behavior itself points to buffer flushing, which occurs according to variable criteria that are hard to predict, as opposed to closing, which occurs under clear-cut and consistent circumstances.

**Conclusion:** `Get-Content -Wait` works exactly as advertised. New content is displayed as soon as it's *physically* written to the file on disk<sup>*</sup>.

It should be noted that my suggestion to disable write caching on the drive did *not* for the test above, i.e. it did not result in `Get-Content -Wait displaying new lines as soon as they're added to the text file by the pipeline, so perhaps the buffering responsible for the output latency is occurring on a filesystem or OS level as opposed to the disk's write cache. However, write buffering is clearly the explanation for the behavior observed in the OP's question.

<sub>* I'm not going to get into this in detail, since it's out of the scope of the question, but `Get-Content -Wait` does behave oddly if you add content to the file not at the end. It displays data from the end of the file equal in size to the amount of data added. The newly displayed data generally repeats data that was previously displayed, and may or may not include any of the new data, depending on whether the size of the new data exceeds the size of the data that follows it.</sub>

Comment: log4net is indeed using the default, flushing after every append. Tried unchecking "Enable write caching on the device" but can't observe any difference, still -wait won't refresh (didn't restart the machine though). If I open the log file with Notepad++, it does notice there was a change. My issue seems to be related with the way PS access the file maybe?

Comment: Downvoting because it is an issue with Powershell.

Comment: @Duncan That's not correct. `Get-Content -Wait` works exactly as described in the documentation. It displays the additional data as soon as the content of the file it's monitoring changes on the disk. The idea that it only displays changes when the file is closed overlooks some observations that have already been noted, but after reading your answer I did some further testing that proves conclusively that this is not the case. I'll add comments under your answer to explain more specifically.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this is a write-cache issue. Even if it *is*, it's an incredible bug in powershell - unless get-content is explicitly documented as bypassing standard file access and somehow going to the raw filesystem, which would be very strange. I've left this running for hours without any updates showing. Unless write caching is fundamentally broken, this wouldn't happen. I'm guessing the underlying file *is* getting updated, but whatever powershell is monitoring is actually something at a higher level, and it's not happening for whatever reason. Very odd.

Comment: ...and after a bit of digging, my guess is it's the file's `Last Modified` date - posted details as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It appears that get-content only works if it goes through the windows api and that versions of appending to a file are different.

```
program.exe > output.txt
```

And then

```
get-content output.txt -wait
```

Will not update.  But

```
program.exe | add-content output.txt
```

will work with.

```
get-content output.txt -wait
```

So I guess it depends on how the application does output.

Comment: Actually piping into `add-content` doesn't work at least not in Powershell v3.0, rather it complains `The process cannot access the file` as unlike redirection `Add-Content` seems to open the file exclusively. If `Get-Content` is started first then it gets all the output when Add-Content terminates. A loop calling Add-Content multiple times will work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to the same issue while trying to watch WindowsUpdate.log in realtime.  While not ideal, the code below allowed me to monitor the progress.  -Wait didn't work due to the same file-writing limitations discussed above.

Displays the last 10 lines, sleeps for 10 seconds, clears the screen and then displays the last 10 again. CTRL + C to stop stream.

```
 while(1){
Get-Content C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log -tail 10 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    Clear 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the loop/sleep syntax - I'm pretty new to PS :) I used it to build a loop that continually "touches" my logfile in the background, and PS picks that up - not sure if the some would work for WindowsUpdate.log with permissions etc., but in case it's of use, check out my edited answer