# Get-Content mosquitto_pub

Tags: powershell, mosquitto

I have a tool that logs some data onto a file. I'd like to tail the file and send the last line of data via [mosquitto_pub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html).
I've used powershell "Get-Content" command without succes.
Here's my command:

`Get-Content -Path "C:\test.txt" -Wait | .\mosquitto_pub.exe -t "Events"`

But nothing is published by mosquitto_pub.

If I use `Get-Content -Path "C:\test.txt" -Wait` 
I see the tail of the file in stdout.

What's wrong with my solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Q and A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919180/get-content-wait-not-working-as-described-in-the-documentation).

An alternate approach

```
$minsToRunFor    = 10
$secondsToRunFor = $minsToRunFor  * 60

foreach ($second in $secondsToRunFor){

    $lastline = Get-Content -Path "C:\test.txt" | Select-Object -last 1

    # added condition as per VonPryz's good point
    # (otherwise will add lastline regardless of whether it's new or not)
    if ($lastline -ne $oldlastline){
         .\mosquitto_pub.exe -t "Events" -m "$lastline"
    }

    $oldlastline = $lastline
    Start-Sleep 100
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this keep sending the last line again and again even if no new content is added?

Comment: Thanks, amended answer.

Comment: ... Unless the file will be appended with same content multiple times. Or it will be appended multiple times during the sleep period...