# keep reading from file, looking for some keywords

Tags: powershell, file, logging

I have a log file that needs to keep monitored that file looking for some keywords, I created a PowerShell script and used the `get-content` command with the `-wait` flag but, `get-content` is just reading the first keyword, and If I remove `-wait` it will work fine and read all keywords, but it will exit after finished, and I want the file to keep waiting for the appended lines.

Please advise me on this.

This is my code:

```
$date = Get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$MyError = @('error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3')
$file=$date.log"
foreach ($i in $MyError) {
Get-Content "$file" -Wait | Select-String -Pattern $i -SimpleMatch | ForEach-Object {
        if ($i -like 'error 1') {
            Write-EventLog -source Test -LogName Test -EventId 1001   -EntryType Error -Message " "
        }

        if ($i -like 'error 2') {
            Write-EventLog -source Test -LogName Test -EventId 1002   -EntryType Error -Message " "
        }

        if ($i -like 'error 3') {
            Write-EventLog -source Test -LogName Test -EventId 1003   -EntryType Error -Message " "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PS are you use? According to this [get-content-wait-not-working-as-described-in-the-documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919180/get-content-wait-not-working-as-described-in-the-documentation) PS under 5.0 version had a bug in Get-Content -wait

Comment: @Przetczak  PS 5.1

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that [`-Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#-wait) blocks the main thread, waits indefinitely until <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>. Because of this, **your outer `foreach` loops only once**, so `$i` is always `error 1`. An easy fix for your problem is to loop inside the `ForEach-Object`, but also, using a [`switch -Wildcard`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2#syntax) would simplify your code:

```
Get-Content path\to\file.txt -Wait | ForEach-Object {
    switch -Wildcard ($_) {
        '*error 1*' {
            # do something for error 1
        }
        '*error 2*' {
            # do something for error 2
        }
        '*error 3*' {
            # do something for error 3
        }
    }
}
```