# How to get the logs from a continuesly running child process in powershell?

Tags: unix, powershell

1. I am calling child process from a process in Powershell.
2. The child process will not end, it will be running continuously in the background.
3. I need the logs entered by the child process continuously.
4. process.standardoutput.rradtoend() will enter the logs into file when the child process ends.

But i need the logs continuously.

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the log to files as below:

```
start-process your_executable -ArgumentList "your arguments" -RedirectStandardOutput the_path_you_want_to_put_your_log -RedirectStandardError the_path_to_put_error_log
```

the logs of the child process will be written to the log files continuously, you can open the files to check them from time to time.

**Edit**

And I think [Unix tail equivalent command in windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell) will do you more help, which tell you how to monitor the log file in real time, like use the `Get-FileTail` Cmdlet from [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)