# View log files in windows command prompt similar to tail command in linux

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a command similar to tail command in linux to view log files in windows.
Linux Command:    $ tail -f /var/log/syslog -f /var/log/myLog.log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell)

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```
type name-of-logfile.log | more
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in Powershell. Replace [filename] with file,

```
Get-Content [filename] -Wait
```

Comment: For the above command i can't follow the update in log file that use to be done using -f in tail command.

Comment: Used the following command:Get-Content -Path C:\wamp\www\tt\app\tmp\logs\error.log -Wait -Tail 10  Error:  A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Tail'

Answer (score 0):

You can download UnxUtils from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/)  which include tail command and other unix commands