# Select a string from a tailing log

Tags: powershell, batch-file, grep, tail

I have an application log for which I am trying to write a batch file that will tail the log and return strings that contain "queue size" so that the updating queue size can be displayed. Basically the Windows equivalent of:

```
tail -f app.log | grep "queue size"
```

From what I've read I would need to use Windows powershell. I have devised the following script:

```
powershell -command Select-String -Path C:\logs\app.log -Pattern "queue size"
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Select-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument 'size'. At line:1 char:1
+ Select-String -Path C:\logs\app.log -Pattern queue size
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Although this as it stands doesn't work, would it constantly update with the current logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the command in double quotes and use single quotes for the pattern:

```
powershell -command "Select-String -Path C:\logs\app.log -Pattern 'queue size'"
```

Comment: Fixes the error, but see @thinkbeforecoding's [`-Wait` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33740461/1751302) for the `tail -f` "constantly update" piece, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556018) from another question

Answer (score 2):

No, the PowerShell command will not continue to read the log as it's being updated. PowerShell can't really handle this task, so you'd be better off grabbing a Windows port of the Unix `tail` command (e.g. from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)) and use it with the batch `find` command:

```
tail -f C:\path\to\app.log | find "queue size"
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do:

```
cat c:\path\to\app.log -tail 100 -wait | select-string "queue size"
```

cat is an alias for Get-Content...
The -wait parameter will make it wait for log updates.