# Windows powershell continuously write file a to file b

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

Hello powershell scripters,

i really can't get this one...

I have fileA.log which will be filled continuously with data.
Now i want to stream this file to a file B in another folder.

On Linux its like

```
tail -f fileA.log > anotherfolder/fileB.log
```

Problem is fileA.log will be rotated two times a day into fileA.log and a new fileA.log will be created.
So the script has to check if fileA.log gets rotated. If so it has to do the same with fileB.log and start a new one automaticly and continue the output from the new fileA.log to the new fileB.log.

I hope i explained it understandable. Anyone can help me out with this?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to simply have whatever's doing the rotating simply append A to B?  plus, if you're doing this to preserve the log file, why rotate+copy? that's lot of disk work when you could simply create new log files each time with a timestamp or something in the filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix tail equivalent command in Windows Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell)

Comment: Okay Problem is:
FileA has to be streamed to a shared folder which is mounted on a linux server. On this Linux server runs an apache. From there FileB will be streamed with jQuery into a web page.
I know it sound really really crazy but there is no other way to do it! 
And no i can't just share the folder which contains fileA! Sadly :(

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate. Using the `-Wait` parameters seems to do the trick. The output file will be locked though while its in progress.